# Problem with lettergothic package in LaTeX/TeXLive

Tags: fonts, texlive

I'm trying to use the [lettergothic package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/lettergothic) in LaTeX for the Letter Gothic monospaced font. According to the [LaTeX Font Catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lettergothic), it would be simple to use it with

```
\usepackage[scaled]{ulgothic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but, for some reason it does not work. After compiling (with `pdflatex`) I get this message (the last lines):

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+12/600 --dpi 612 ulgb8rmktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ulgb8r.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ulgb8r): Font ulgb8r at 612 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 70 at Wed Aug 15 00:46:57
```

I can't understand why this is happening since I have all the files installed on my system. I've installed all nonfree fonts (which Letter Gothic belongs) with

```
$ sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a
```

and `sudo updmap-sys` and `sudo texhash`. All the files are where they were supposed to be.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with `texlive` and with both `texlive-fonts-recommended` and `texlive-fonts-extra`

The location path for the files are (summarizing):

```
$ sudo find / -iname ulg*
/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/ulg/ulgothic.sty
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/vf/urw/lettrgth/ulgb*.vf
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/afm/urw/lettergothic/ulgb*.afm
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/ulg/ulg.map
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/urw/lettrgth/ulgb*.tfm
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/type1/urw/lettergothic/ulgb*.pfb
```

The path for `pdftex.map` is

```
$ kpsewhich pdftex.map
/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

Comment: Please, can you edit your answer and write down the path to the location of the letter gothic files, just one or two, just to make sure, where they are. And could you have a look at the properties of those files?

Comment: You haven't activated the map-file correctly. Try `updmap-sys --enable Map ulg.map`. If this doesn't work, show the path of your `pdftex.map` (`kpsewhich pdftex.map`).

Comment: @KeksDose the location path is now at the question body. I hope that is the information you asked. @Ulrike the `updmap-sys` command didn't work. I updated the question with the path of `pdftex.map`.

Comment: Please see [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).