# How to install a font in Windows?

Tags: fonts, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXworks 0.4.3 and have to use a specific font(Frutiger) provided by my university.

The entire Latex template is available for download here:
https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/ddis/oldweb/ddis/fileadmin/theses/general/DDIS-diploma-thesis-template-en.zip

The standalone font file is available here: https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/ddis/oldweb/ddis/fileadmin/teaching/BaKoMa/frutiger.tar.gz

According to the readme file, I have to install it like this:

```
 Windows Installation Notes
==========================

Usual location of texmf folder:

C:\texmf

1/ Copy the file frutiger.tar.gz into the parent directory of your texmf
folder (probably C:\).

2/ Unzip the file.

3/ Edit the file c:\texmf\miktex\config\updmap.cfg. (In case it
does not yet exist, create it as a new file.)  Add the line

Map frutiger.map

and save the file; then execute the following commands 
in a command line window ("DOS shell"):

initexmf -u
updmap
```

I tried it without any success and googled for hours - looks like I'm lost...

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Though here are two answers right now I want to point you to [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**create a local texmf tree**

If no local texmf tree exists, you can create the folder `C:/localtexmf`. The subtrees you need depend on what you want to install into this directory, but in your case it should be sufficient to include the following:

```
C:/localtexmf/doc/latex
             /tex/latex
```

Then go to MikTeX's *Settings (Admin)* in the Start Menu, click on the *Roots* tab and add `C:/localtexmf`. Next click on the *General* tab and click on *Refresh FNDB*.

Complete instructions for the creation of a local texmf tree in MiKTeX can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/14497). More information on TDS compliance can be found [here](http://tug.org/tds/tds.html).

**install fonts**

Unzip `frutiger.tar.gz` and copy its contents into the correct locations, e.g., the file

```
frutiger/texmf/dvips/base/frutiger.map
```

would go in `C:/localtexmf/dvips/base`, the folder

```
frutiger/texmf/fonts/tfm/adobe/frutiger
```

would go in `C:/localtexmf/fonts/tfm/adobe/frutiger`, etc.

Next, on the Windows command prompt, type

```
initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap
```

then add the line

```
Map frutiger.map
```

and save. Afterwards, run

```
 initexmf -u
 initexmf --mkmaps
```

Finally, refresh the FNDB. Try running `kpsewhich frutiger.map` on the Windows command prompt. It should return the location of the map file; if it doesn't, somehow it is not visible to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pfr}

\begin{document}
abs \textsf{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I appreciate your step by step guide a lot - would still sitting here and figuring out what to do without your help!

Comment: Thanks you - I would have never figured this out without your help!

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't put files in the main miktex folder. Better do it this way:

Unpack the tar.gz in an empty folder outside your miktex. E.g. in `C:\frutiger`. 
After unpacking you should have a folder `texmf` inside `C:\frutiger`. In `texmf` create a folder `miktex` and in `miktex` a folder `config`. Then create in the `config` folder a file `updmap.cfg` with the content

```
Map frutiger.map
```

Then go to miktex settings and add in the tab "roots" `C:\frutiger\texmf` as a new root.

Then run on the command line

```
updmap
```

At last test the font with this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder about not installing fonts directly in the main folder. Having read your answer, I then added notes on mine on how to create a local texmf tree.