# External font with portable MiKTeX, Version 2.9

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex

I have an external font and be able to use it in my documents on my desktop computer with MiKTeX 2.9.

Now I try to use the same font with portable MiKTeX 2.9. The external font is located in my local TeXFM.  With normal MiKTeX I need to call

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

to open the local file `updmap.cfg` for inserting `Map thefont.map`. Portable MiKTeX (starting from the Command Prompt you get from the taskbar entry for MiKTeX portable) opens the system `updmap.cfg` in `<portable-MiKTeX>\miktex\config`, which is changed always you update portable MiKTeX.

It is a quick and very dirty workaround to change the system file until the next update, but how can I tell portable MiKTeX to use the external font and remember it over the next update?

For me this is an unwanted behavior, I would tend to see it as a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be an unwanted/unexpected behaviour, but it is the consequence of setting all MiKTeX variables *(see also “Additional Note” in [my answer to “Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/9237))* to one folder to be in portable mode. You can check this yourself by executing `initexmf --report` from the command prompt provided by MiKTeX portable from its taskbar entry.

So, for MiKTeX portable the approach must be a bit different from [my answer to “Manual font installation”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88424/9237). Some remarks:

1. Exactly as in “normal” MiKTeX the local TeXMF directory **must** be outside of the directory structure of MiKTeX itself. It must be on the same drive, of course. The path is saved relative then.
2. OpenType/TrueType fonts: No problems with installation in local TeXMF path here, but the execution of `fc-cache` will always scan the system fonts, usually in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. So when you use MiKTeX portable in the way, as it is originally thought for (on a removable drive), *you have to refresh the font-cache each time you plug the removable drive on another computer*.
3. After adding all Type1 fonts and relatives in your portable local TeXMF do **not** execute `initexmf --edit-config-file=updmap.cfg` or the slightly shorter form: This will open MiKTeX’ main `updmap.cfg`, that will be overwritten on your next update!

   Instead, create an empty file `updmap.cfg` by hand in `<MiKTeX-portable_localtexmf>\miktex\config`, open this with your favorite text editor, and add the needed Map entries there (you can _look _ into the main `updmap.cfg` to see how this has to be done). Do not forget to refresh the filename database and format files. It may be necessary to add the `--force` option (it was not for me, but was reported by others and does not hurt): `initexmf --update-fndb --force` (or shorter `initexmf -u --force`), followed by `initexmf --mkmaps --force` (or shorter `updmap --force`).

Comment: Thank you so very much! I had to run ´texhash --force --update-fndb´, then ´updmap --force´ and then ´texhash --force --update-fndb´ again, before it worked. But it was your description that put me in right direction.

Comment: @Sveinung: `texhash` is just an alias for `initexmf`.