# How to use (install) LegacySans

Tags: fonts

I find a nice font LegacySans and I would use it in my works. I don't know how to install it in Latex distribution. Some idea?

Answer (score 3):

That depends.

If you found the font in PostScript format, follow the directions at [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation); after that, you will be able to compile your documents with your preferred engine.

If you found it in OpenType format, install it the same way you would with fonts you don’t plan to use in LaTeX (the details depend on your operating system), and compile your document with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

I have the book and medium weights of this font; I rarely use bold, but this example shows how one could make the medium weight serve as a sort of semibold:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle,
  ItalicFont={* Italic},
  BoldFont={Legacy Sans ITC Pro Medium},
  BoldItalicFont={Legacy Sans ITC Pro Medium Italic}]
{Legacy Sans ITC Pro Book}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Legacy Sans}

  The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.

  \textit{The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.}

  The quick \textbf{bold fox} jumps over a \textsc{lazy dog}.

  1234567890
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample of Legacy Sans]

Comment: Just a sidenote: You can install OPen-/TrueType fonts in a texmf tree, as well. There is also something written in (the already linked by you) [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)