# How to install font from the font catalogue in Debian

Tags: fonts, installing, ubuntu, debian

As it seems many users have a problem with this in Debian and/or Ubuntu. I have not seen a good an straightforward guide in various forums. Finally I found it out, just by reading the documentation. I'll answer my own post below.

Comment: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation). Or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Still the procedure is different.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the font to install. http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html is an excellent place. It provides pointers to the fonts files. In my case I tried to install **emerald**.

The font can be downloaded from a CTAN mirror: http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/. Download the `.zip`, and unzip it in a temporary directory. Once unzipped, a directory tree has been created which looks like:

```
emerald--doc
       \-fonts
       \-other
       \-tex
```

Now the *correct* guide for installation on Debian can be found here: http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/ch4.html Proceed to section 4.3.

The intention is to install the font files in ***TEXMFLOCAL***. In Debian, this defaults to **/usr/local/share/texmf/**. This is not obvious, as this directory is empty and no-one would assume something is to be installed here.

In case something has already been installed, use this recursive copy command:

```
emerald$ sudo rsync -auv ../emerald/ /usr/local/share/texmf/.
```

Note that this command must be issued from the emerald temporary directory as mentioned before. This will create a directory tree which looks like:

```
/usr/local/share/texmf--docs--
                      |
                      \-fonts--afm
                      |      \-map
                      |      \-tfm
                      |      \-type1
                      |      \-vf
                      |
                      \-other--
                      |
                      \-tex--
```

When this is done correctly, follow steps 1-5 exactly as described on the Debian installation guide. Command have to be entered as root.

Finally, a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\normalfont\ECFJD
\lipsum
\end{document}
```