# Install font on Mac

Tags: fonts, installing

I have been trying to install a font called Frutiger that I have in a zip file `myfonts.zip` using this [guide on TUG site](http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html). By the way, I'm on a Mac with MacTeX. The zip file has this tree structure:

```
myfonts/dvips/psfonts/frutiger.map
myfonts/fonts/amf/frutiger/*.amf files
myfonts/fonts/tmf/frutiger/*.tmf files
myfonts/fonts/type1/frutiger/*.pfb files
myfonts/fonts/vf/frutiger/*.vf files
myfonts/tex/latex/psnfss/*.fd files
```

I have put the above files into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`.
For example `myfont.map` is in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/dvips/psfonts/frutiger.map` and so on.

Then I did these steps:

```
1. Run 'sudo -H mktexlsr' in the console.
2. Run 'sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=myfont.map'
3. Run 'sudo -H mktexlsr' again.
```

In my .tex file I added `\usepackage{frutiger}`. When I run my .tex file with PDFLaTeX I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `frutiger.sty' not found.
```

I have tried to download and put `frutiger.sty` in the same folder as my .tex file but the new font is not showing up. I have tried the above steps several times but it does not seem like the font is being installed correctly. Last time I got this output in the console.

```
1. sudo -H mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.

2. sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=frutiger.map
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.

3. sudo -H mktexlsr
mktexlsr: ... Same as in step 1 ....
```

Do you have any clue on what could be wrong?

EDIT:
Here is the content of `frutiger.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{frutiger}
    [2005/08/08 v1.2 Style file for Linotype Frutiger]
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\DeclareOption{lining}{\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{lfrx}}
\DeclareOption{oldstyle}{\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{lfrj}}
\ExecuteOptions{oldstyle}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%%
%% End of file 'frutiger.sty'
```

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frutiger}
\title{\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section I}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Adding `\usepackage{frutiger}` doesn't change the font more than that bold text becomes normal. I have checked the zip file and it seems to be okay as I can read the files with an editor. Also, I tried to force the map to be recreated using `sudo -H updmap-sys --force --enable Map=frutiger.map`. AFAIK there is no difference. Adding `\fontfamily{pfr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont` before any text makes the text look like Frutiger, I don't know if it actually is real Frutiger though. How do I find out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What happens if you have `frutiger.sty` in the same folder as the document?

Comment: Frutiger is a sans serif font. If you add `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` after `\usepackage{frutiger}` you'll get it as main text font.

Comment: `frutiger.sty` should go in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/frutiger` (remember `sudo mktexlsr`). Can you add the contents of `frutiger.sty`?

Comment: Can you copy the contents of `frutiger.sty` and paste it into your question?

Comment: Does [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) help you?

Comment: What happens, if you change the location of the map file first, and run the updates afterwards again? New location: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/frutiger/frutiger.map`. And: They should be found in `psnfss` anyway, but I wonder, why the `*.fd` files (and, as egreg already wrote, `frutiger.sty`) are not in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/frutiger`.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of a LaTeX document that shows the problem? If LaTeX doesn't find a requested font it raises an error; or the error is raised at the moment the Type1 font must be used to produce a page. If you get no error and no Frutiger font, then you're *not* requesting that font to begin with.

Comment: Is there a `force` option? See with `sudo updmap-sys --help`. The ZIP file is not partly defunct? You can read the MAP file and the FD files with a texteditor? Technical remark: For pinging another user address him with `@` in the beginning, e.g. `@Speravir` (cf. commenting help).

Comment: I've marked as a dupe of the more general question: if this one still needs to be addressed in more detail, flag and I'll reopen.