# How (La)TeX makes use of font related files, i.e., .fd, .map, .enc, .def,etc when selecting fonts?

Tags: fonts

What are the usage of these font related files: `.fd`, `.map`, `.enc`, `.def`, etc?

What's the sequence of using them when `(La)TeX` converts tokens to generate a `pdf` output(assuming `pdftex` is the engine)?

By the way, would you please provide me with some documentations that covers this topic?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Quick Overview

- [TeX font errors: Cheatsheet](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tex-font-errors-cheatsheet) (A simple overview. Very useful for you now, I guess.)

[image]

### Some related books:

- LaTeX Companion 2ed, Chapter 7: Fonts and Encodings. Especially 7.9 -- 7.11. (`.fd`, `.def`, `.enc`, `.map`)
- TeXbook, Appendix F: Font Tables. (`.tfm`)
- METAFONTbook. (`.tfm`, `.gf`)

### Documents:

- [The LaTeX Graphics Companion: Supplementary material.](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/tlgc2extra.pdf) (A lot of things you want to know, mainly about Type1 fonts.)
- [`fntguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fntguide) LaTeX 2 font selection. (`.fd`, `.def`)
- [`encguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/encguide) LaTeX font encodings. (`.def`)
- [`fontinstallationguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontinstallationguide) The Font Installation Guide. (Maybe everything you want to know, mainly for Type1 fonts. But some materials are outdated today.)

### Tools:

- [`dvips`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/dvips) (`.cfg`, `.map`, `.enc`, `.vf`, etc.)
- [`pdftex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdftex) (`.enc`, `.map`, etc.)
- [`dvipdfm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/dvipdfm) (`.enc`, `.map`, etc.)
- `dvipdfmx`: See `dvipdfm` and comments in `cid-x.map`.
- [`updmap`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/updmap) (`updmap.cfg`, `.map`)
- [`ttf2tfm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ttf2tfm) (`.ttf` --> `.tfm`, `.enc`; CMap files)
- [`ttf2pk`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ttf2pk) (`.ttf` --> `.pk`; `ttfonts.map`)
- `ttf2pt1` (`.ttf` --> `.pfb`)
- [`gftopk`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/gftopk) (`.gf` --> `.pk`)

### And More...

For XeTeX and LuaTeX, you can search and read the documents yourself. That's another story.

Comment: your answer is much more than I need, Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

## `.def` files

In files such as `t1enc.def` LaTeX finds definitions for tuning the choice of glyphs to the current encoding. There is always a *current output encoding* and some commands change their behavior depending on it; for instance `\"{o}` will translate to `\accent"7F o` if the current encoding is OT1 (or other encodings that don't have a “ö” glyph in their set), but the same `\"{o}` instruction will become `\char"F6` if the current encoding is T1.

These files are read in as soon as the package `fontenc` is loaded with the encoding in its options. This package can be loaded multiple times; some packages, for instance `textcomp` load it implicitly. The current encoding at `\begin{document}` will be the one corresponding to the option passed *last* to `fontenc`.

There are other `.def` files, but those not named `<encoding>enc.def` are not related to fonts.

## `.fd` files

When you specify `\fontfamily{<family>}\selectfont` (which might be implicit in a declaration such as `\ttfamily` or in a command such as `\textsf`), LaTeX looks in its internal tables in order to see if the combination

```
<encoding>+<family>
```

is known, where `<encoding>` is the current encoding. Such a knowledge comes from having already seen a declaration

```
\DeclareFontFamily{<encoding>}{<family>}{<tokens>}
```

Let's assume the current encoding is T1 and the requested family is `ppl` (Palatino). If the combination `T1+ppl` isn't known (which, by the way, is checked against the definedness of the control sequence `\T1+ppl`), LaTeX tries to load the file `t1ppl.fd` or `T1ppl.fd`. If neither exists, LaTeX will issue a warning and substitute the requested family with a default, but it will *not* change the encoding.

A `.fd` file should start with a `\DeclareFontFamily` declaration, followed by any number of `\DeclareFontShape` declarations that set up a table for the requested pair `<encoding>+<family>`. See [`fntguide.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fntguide.pdf) for details.

Commands of the form `\DeclareFontFamily` or `\DeclareFontShape` can appear also in the document's preamble. The latter commands *must* follow a suitable font family declaration. Each of these declarations will establish a correspondence between a choice of attributes for a font and a “font metric file”. In our example, the combination

```
\usefont{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}
```

or any equivalent choice will point to `pplb8t`. A font metric file can be of two forms: a `.vf` or a `.tfm` file. If `pplb8t.vf` exists, TeX (we are deep down the processing, now) will load it, otherwise it will load `pplb8t.tfm`. One of these *must* exist.

The `\DeclareFontShape` commands can establish font substitutions and other rules; if LaTeX doesn't find its way out, it will choose a default font. However, badly written `.fd` files or improper `\DeclareFontShape` commands in the document can lead to errors (`Corrupt NFSS tables`).

So, let's assume that TeX has found `pplb8t.vf` or `pplb8t.tfm`.

## `.vf` files

A font metric file can be *virtual*. This is indeed the case for `pplb8t`. The `.vf` metric file contains information about character bounding boxes, italic corrections, kerning pairs and ligatures. It also contains information for choosing actual glyphs from other fonts (virtual or not). In our example, the virtual font only uses a nonvirtual font which is `pplb8r`

```
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME pplb8r)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 25012244013)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

and basically shuffles around the glyphs positions to conform with the T1 output encoding. For instance, the character in slot `"F7` (octal `` `367 ``) has this entry in the `pplb8t.vf` file

```
(CHARACTER O 367
   (CHARWD R 0.832996)
   (CHARHT R 0.485498)
   (CHARDP R 0.011493)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 234)
      )
   )
```

This means that the glyph `œ` (which might come from the command `\oe`) will be actually taken from the font `pplb8r` at slot octal `` `234 `` (hexadecimal `"9C`), but the user is not concerned about this. The bounding box for the glyph will be computed has having width 8.32996pt, height 4.85498pt, depth 0.11493pt and no italic correction (assuming a ten point font size has been requested, otherwise the dimensions will be scaled).

## `.tfm` files

A `.tfm` file (and in the previous case `pplb8r.tfm` *must* exist) contains the same information as a `.vf` file, except the possibility to point to other font metric files.

## Interlude

As far as TeX is concerned, the road stops here: characters are typeset and a page is shipped out. The printer/previewer driver will take care of actually showing the glyphs. The situation is different with pdfTeX that needs to store also the glyphs.

## `.map` files

Our boldface glyph `œ` has eventually been taken from `pplb8r`. Now pdfTeX consults the loaded `.map` file (default `pdftex.map`) and look for an entry starting with `pplb8r`. It finds it as

```
pplb8r URWPalladioL-Bold " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <uplb8a.pfb
```

so it proceeds to load the Type1 font file `upl8a.pfb` (if it hasn't yet loaded it), but it will apply a *reencoding*. This is necessary because `.pfb` files are stored according to the Adobe Standard Encoding and some glyphs are hidden. So the driver will shuffle around glyphs ending with a font encoded according to the `8r` encoding (similar to T1 or the others, but not recommended for usage in documents). In this way the `œ` glyph will really be in slot `"F7`, rather than in the `"FA` slot reserved in the Adobe Standard Encoding. The glyph `ö` even isn't in the Adobe Standard Encoding, but still lives *unencoded* in the `.pfb` file; with the reencoding to `8r` we're able to use it in slot `"F6`.

Why the change from `pplb8a` to `uplb8a`? Because the font actually used is the free one provided by URW. This doesn't really concern the user.

## `.pfb` files

These files contain representations of the glyphs for printing (or previewing) in the form of outlines. Such files are never loaded directly by users, but only from the engine or the printer/previewer driver. They can also be in the `.pfa` form, the difference is that `.pfa` files only contain printable ASCII characters and so are larger than a corresponding `.pfb` file.

Comment: Good complement to Leo Liu's answer, thank you!

Comment: A great explanation!

Comment: When I downloaded a Type-1 font it had .pfm and .pfb files inside of it. =)

Comment: @71GA The necessary infrastructure has to be built; try `texdoc fontinstallationguide`

Comment: Hi @egreg! You said that `.pfa` only contains printable ASCII characters. AFAIK, the printable ones in ASCII is a subset of the whole ASCII. Taking this into consideration, I guess the `.pfa` files would be smaller in file size than their corresponding `.pfb` files. However, the result that you gave is `.pfa` files would be larger. I wonder if there is any mistake here. Thanks! `: )`

Comment: @Ch'enMeng I'm referring to the file format, not to its contents. A `.pfa` font file and its `.pfb` counterpart are completely equivalent; only the data is represented in different forms.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Do you mean that information stored in `.pfa` files are the same as those in `.pfb` files, and the only difference is they are stored in different format (like `xml` files and `json` files)?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Exactly so

Comment: Hi @egreg, I'm interested in translating your post into Chinese and put it on my own blog. Would you like to give me the permission? Thank you!

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Of course! Please, post the link.

Comment: Hi @egreg, I've translated the post into Chinese. I bloged it [here](http://liam0205.me/2016/12/11/LaTeX-traditional-font-scheme/), as you could see that I put your name and the link to this post at the top of the body. There are two QRCode in the bottom of the page for donation. As I mentioned in the end of the blog, the income of this blog will be donated to the Chinese TeX society to support the development of TeX in China. I hope you'll be satisfied with this. : )

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Sure! :-)

Comment: There is a typo in section ".vf files", the hex number `"F7"` should be `"F7`. I failed to edit the answer since tex.sx requires that "Edits must be at least 6 characters."

Comment: @JohannesZ Fixed, thanks