# pk: how to compute the advance of a given glyph

Tags: fonts, png, dvi

I am working on a Go library that reads a `.dvi` file and produces a `.png` file.
I have already the packages that find+parse `.tfm` and `.pk` files working: I have the `pk2bm`, `tfm2pl` and `dvitype` equivalent executables producing a bit-to-bit compliant output with the ones from `tex-live`.

now, I would like to be able to replicate the functionality of `dvipng` in Go (and I'd like to keep out of the sources of `dvipng` to keep my packages licensed under BSD-3.)

from first principles, I think I managed to correctly extract the bitmap data from the `.pk` file and display each glyph, but I am not sure whether:

- I have correctly scaled them
- I have a correctly scaled bounding box
- I have a correctly scaled horizontal advance value.

here is what I get, trying to display the string `VA` (outside the `dvi` "machinery", just getting the `V` and `A` glyphs, taking their bounding boxes, drawing the bitmap of each glyph, and then moving the "dot" with the glyph-advance (I haven't included kerning just yet)):

[image]

obviously, my handling of the width of each glyph is subpar.

Let's say I have the following `tfm` package:

```golang
package tfm

type fileBody struct {
        header  header
        glyphs  []glyphInfo
        width   []fixed.Int12_20
        height  []fixed.Int12_20
        depth   []fixed.Int12_20
        italic  []fixed.Int12_20
        ligKern []ligKernCmd
        kern    []fixed.Int12_20
        exten   []extensible
        param   []fixed.Int12_20
}

type header struct {
        chksum       uint32
        designSize   fixed.Int12_20
        codingScheme string
        fontID       string
        sevenBitSafe bool
        face         byte

        extra []fixed.Int12_20
}

type glyphInfo struct {
        raw [4]uint8
}
```

and the following `pk` font package:

```golang
package pkf

// Font is a Packed Font.
type Font struct {
        hdr    CmdPre
        glyphs []Glyph
}

type CmdPre struct {
        Version  uint8
        Msg      string
        Design   uint32
        Checksum uint32
        Hppp     uint32
        Vppp     uint32
}

// Glyph represents a glyph contained in a PK font file.
type Glyph struct {
        flag   uint8
        code   uint32 // character code
        wtfm   uint32 // TFM width
        dx     uint32 // horizontal escapement
        dy     uint32 // vertical escapement
        width  uint32 // width in pixels of the minimum bounding box
        height uint32 // height in pixels of the minimum bounding box
        hoff   int32  // horizontal offset from the upper left pixel
        voff   int32  // vertical offset from the upper left pixel

        bitmap []byte // decoded bitmap data
}
```

how should I scale all of these, when starting with `"pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk"` and `"tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm"` as inputs, and trying to draw `VAp` into a `((0,0) , (500, 250))` PNG image? (with a 'dot' at `(0, 100)`)

(and I'd like to scale this to a 10pt + 600DPI image.)

Comment: Have you looked at the output of dvitype? Does it help?

Comment: It's been a while so I've forgotten, but see if something here helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360137/how-to-generate-a-bitmap-using-tex-with-bitmap-fonts

Comment: @ShreevatsaR yeah, I managed to do something along these lines (using "my" version of `dvitype` (called `dvi-dump`)). it only works for the "natural" DPI of the `pk` font as I don't have the tooling to rescale the `pk` font for the user's input.

Comment: see the output: [hello.png](https://git.sr.ht/~sbinet/star-tex/blob/main/cmd/dvi-cnv/testdata/hello_golden.png) and [xcolor.png](https://git.sr.ht/~sbinet/star-tex/blob/main/cmd/dvi-cnv/testdata/xcolor_golden.png)

Comment: Ah cool... Instead of rescaling the `pk` font, the ultimate ideal AFAICT would be to run Metafont at the desired resolution: this may be impractical as it may result in too much computation or disk space (one set of pk fonts for each desired resolution, like `600pk`, `500pk`, …), but then again that may be ok.

Comment: yes, ultimately, having a Go-based solution for Metafont would be great. but I think I'll direct my meager development workforce towards `type1` support and climb up the ladder of deprecated fonts :)

Answer (score 2):

ok... progress.
it's not completely satisfying, but -- unless somebody has more insight -- I'll try to make do with this.

I've converted `lmroman10-regular.otf` to `pk`:

```sh
$> ttf2tfm lmroman10-regular.otf -q -T T1-WGL4.enc \
  -v lmroman10-regular.vpl                         \
  lmroman10-regular.tfm  >> ./ttfonts.map
$> ttf2pk lmroman10-regular 600
```

to be sure I was comparing apples to apples.

then, after trial and error, and looking at what the advance+glyph-bounds of `A` in the `.otf` file should look like, I got:

```golang
i := tfmFile.indexOf('A') // retrieve the glyph index for 'A'
w := tfmFile.width[i] + tfmFile.italic[i] // take into account italic correction
advance := int26_6_From_Int12_20(w) // Go fonts work with 26.6 fixed point ints
advance *= pkFont.UnitsPerEm() // 1000 for most (all?) PK fonts
advance /= 1<<6                // some more 26.6 fiddling?

advance = rescale(pkFont.scale * advance, pkFont.UnitsPerEm())
```

where:

```golang
// rescale returns x divided by unitsPerEm, rounded to the nearest fixed.Int26_6
// value (1/64th of a pixel).
func rescale(x fixed.Int26_6, unitsPerEm int32) fixed.Int26_6 {
        if x >= 0 {
                x += fixed.Int26_6(unitsPerEm) / 2
        } else {
                x -= fixed.Int26_6(unitsPerEm) / 2
        }
        return x / fixed.Int26_6(unitsPerEm)
}
```

and `pkFont.scale` is:

```golang
opts.Size = tfmFile.DesignSize().AsFloat64()
opts.DPI = 600.0
pkFont.scale = fixed.Int26_6(0.5 + (opts.Size * opts.DPI * 64 / 72))
```

in the end, I get, for the `lmroman10-regular.otf` (with the bounding boxes drawn around each glyph):
[image]

and for the `lmroman10-regular.600pk` file produced following the instructions above:

[image]

there are some differences.
but I'll take this as a win.