# pk: height, ascend, descend and cap-height of a pk font face

Tags: fonts, dvi, font-metrics

still working on my `dvi-to-png` program in Go ([[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614757/pk-how-to-compute-the-advance-of-a-given-glyph)), I am trying to shoehorn face metrics from `pk` and `tfm` into this structure from "the" Go font library:

```golang
package font // import "golang.org/x/image/font"

// Metrics holds the metrics for a Face. A visual depiction is at
//  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Art/glyph_metrics_2x.png
type Metrics struct {
    // Height is the recommended amount of vertical space between two lines of
    // text.
    Height fixed.Int26_6

    // Ascent is the distance from the top of a line to its baseline.
    Ascent fixed.Int26_6

    // Descent is the distance from the bottom of a line to its baseline. The
    // value is typically positive, even though a descender goes below the
    // baseline.
    Descent fixed.Int26_6

    // XHeight is the distance from the top of non-ascending lowercase letters
    // to the baseline.
    XHeight fixed.Int26_6

    // CapHeight is the distance from the top of uppercase letters to the
    // baseline.
    CapHeight fixed.Int26_6

    // CaretSlope is the slope of a caret as a vector with the Y axis pointing up.
    // The slope {0, 1} is the vertical caret.
    CaretSlope image.Point
}
```

[image: img]

I could extract from the `TFM` data:

- `XHeight` (*ie:* `param[5]`, `x_height`)
- `CaretSlope` (*ie:* `param[1]`, `slant`)

am I right in assuming there's no direct equivalent for the other quantities?
at least not from directly the `tfm` nor `pk` data.
I guess they could be inferred by going through all ASCII letters and applying some heuristics:

- `A...Z`: largest `height` assumed to correspond to `CapHeight`
- `a...z`: largest `height` assumed to correspond to `Ascent`
- `a...z`: largest `depth` assumed to correspond to `Descent`

assuming the above heuristics holds, I would still be missing `Height` (or "Line height" in the picture above).

any ideas?

---

*EDIT:* well, it seems the heuristics for `Ascent` and `Descent` lead to bogus results (smaller values than what is expected). the one for `CapHeight` gives a reasonable result. (smaller, but ball park-ishly ok)

Comment: Are you aware that some characters of a font may extend beyond the (x-)height for visual reasons? For example the letter O will be a tiny bit larger in height than the letter E in order to make the two visually equally high. I am not sure that you will be able to get the correct ascent or descent of a font by just scanning all lowercase Latin letters.

Comment: yeah, I think I'll just leave it like that: better to provide no information than incorrect one.

except if there *is* a way to get at these from TFM and/or PK font files... ?