# TeXLive- installing a Type - 1 font

Tags: fonts

I got a .zip file with some font files inside it - they look like this:

- MO-DLRG_.PFB
- MO-DLRG_.PFM

I put these two files into a folder `~/texmf/fonts/type1/sckr` and then I ran commands:

```
sudo texhash ~/texmf
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=fontname.map
sudo texhash ~/texmf
```

But when I try to include my fonts in my dcument which looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sckr}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    {\sckr primer}

\end{document}
```

I get an error saying that `sckr.sty` not found. Can anyone help me with this one?

---

**ADD**: So I only got `.pfb` and `.pfm` files from a vendor, but in a Lehman's tutorial it says that I also need `.afm` file.

[image]

Now I copied my files in a directory and renamed them to be `sckr.pfb` and `sckr.pfm` (I only watched out that name is shorter than 8 chars like sugested in fontname.pdf written by Berry) and didnt bother with other renaming conventions.

then I added this fontinst file named `pfb-drv.tex` into the same folder:

```
\input fontinst.sty
\recordtransforms{psb-rec.tex}
    \latinfamily{psb}{}
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
```

And I ran it using command

```
tex psb-drv.tex
```

And what I get is a lot of errors:

```
[ziga@Ziga-laptop sckr (normal)]$ tex psb-drv.tex 
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=tex)
(./psb-drv.tex (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/fontinst/base/fontinst.sty
No file fontinst.rc.
)
INFO> parse family <psb><>
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,n,> seek psbr8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sc,> seek psbrc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sl,> seek psbro8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,it,> seek psbri8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,n,c> seek psbr8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sc,c> seek psbrc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sl,c> seek psbro8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,it,c> seek psbri8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,n,> seek psbk8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sc,> seek psbkc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sl,> seek psbko8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,it,> seek psbki8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,n,c> seek psbk8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sc,c> seek psbkc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,sl,c> seek psbko8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,m,it,c> seek psbki8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,n,> seek psbb8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,sc,> seek psbbc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,sl,> seek psbbo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,it,> seek psbbi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,n,c> seek psbb8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,sc,c> seek psbbc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,sl,c> seek psbbo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,b,it,c> seek psbbi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,n,> seek psbs8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,sc,> seek psbsc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,sl,> seek psbso8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,it,> seek psbsi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,n,c> seek psbs8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,sc,c> seek psbsc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,sl,c> seek psbso8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,sb,it,c> seek psbsi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,n,> seek psbd8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,sc,> seek psbdc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,sl,> seek psbdo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,it,> seek psbdi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,n,c> seek psbd8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,sc,c> seek psbdc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,sl,c> seek psbdo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,db,it,c> seek psbdi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,n,> seek psbm8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,sc,> seek psbmc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,sl,> seek psbmo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,it,> seek psbmi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,n,c> seek psbm8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,sc,c> seek psbmc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,sl,c> seek psbmo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,mb,it,c> seek psbmi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,> seek psbc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,> seek psbcc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,> seek psbco8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,> seek psbci8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,c> seek psbc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,c> seek psbcc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,c> seek psbco8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,c> seek psbci8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,> seek psbh8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,> seek psbhc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,> seek psbho8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,> seek psbhi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,c> seek psbh8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,c> seek psbhc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,c> seek psbho8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,c> seek psbhi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,> seek psbx8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,> seek psbxc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,> seek psbxo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,> seek psbxi8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,n,c> seek psbx8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sc,c> seek psbxc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,sl,c> seek psbxo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,eb,it,c> seek psbxi8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,n,> seek psbu8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,sc,> seek psbuc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,sl,> seek psbuo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,it,> seek psbui8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,n,c> seek psbu8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,sc,c> seek psbuc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,sl,c> seek psbuo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,ub,it,c> seek psbui8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,n,> seek psbl8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,sc,> seek psblc8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,sl,> seek psblo8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,it,> seek psbli8r.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,n,c> seek psbl8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,sc,c> seek psblc8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,sl,c> seek psblo8rn.mtx
INFO> to make LaTeX font shape <psb,l,it,c> seek psbli8rn.mtx
Font definitions written on 8rpsb.fd.
Font definitions written on ot1psb.fd.
Font definitions written on t1psb.fd.
Font definitions written on ts1psb.fd.
Font transformation records written on psb-rec.tex.
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on psb-drv.log.
```

I am sure I wrote something wrong...

Comment: Running `texhash` on a personal TEXMF tree is unnecessary and entirely pointless. This tree is searched directly (unless you've changed the default) and does not use a database. Installing fonts into your personal TEXMF tree is somewhat dubious. However, the main problem here is that you have not installed anything else. For example, you don't mention installing a `sckr.sty` file, so it is not surprising it cannot be found. You also would need a `.map` and `.tfm` files, at least. You must have got a warning when you ran `updmap-sys`?? Don't ignore errors and warnings!

Comment: To expand slightly: if this is just an arbitrary type1 font you cannot use it with (pdf)TeX without preparing a set of support files for it. This includes at least `.tfm` and `.map` files. Usually also `.fd`, `.sty` and, possibly, `.vf` and/or `.enc`. Without these files, the font is useless. Do you have these files or only the `.pfb` and `pfm` files? Oh, and you don't need `sudo` to write to your personal `texmf` tree unless you have a very odd configuration indeed. And don't use `utf8x` rather than `utf8` if you can help it.

Comment: I provide some references in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577/best-practices-references/150466#150466). The Font Installation Guide explains the process required to create the support files needed to use an arbitrary type1 font with (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. It looks like I am a big noob to this font installation. I only have `.pfb` and `.pfm` files so it looks like I have to prepare this font for LaTeX. I will check the link you provided and will try to figure it out. If I get any problems I wont hesitate to add a coment here.

Comment: It is something of a minority sport....

Comment: the document that you pointed out is pointing to another 300 page document. I already gave up...

Comment: You can probably follow the basic tutorial in the Font Installation Guide without reading anything else, even if it advises you to. Definitely don't read `fontinst`'s manual or `fontname`. The former is probably very good but I can't say for sure as I've never been able to decipher it. The latter is useful but only for reference. Most of it is lists of font names.

Comment: I did follow the basic tutorial and tried to get tex files that I need in order to install the font, but it didn't work. Can you please check the **ADD** to my post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28826/discussion-between-cfr-and-71ga).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to start recording this for the sake of posterity, should posterity turn out to be interested ;. This works for me (as discussed in chat) but the OP is still having a few `fontinst` teething troubles.

This answer assumes a Unix-ish system such as GNU/Linux, OS X, BSD or similar. It will not work unmodified on Windows.

## Introduction

To use a font with (pdf)(La)TeX, you need a good number of support files in addition to the type1 font itself.

This answer is based on the initial, basic `fontinst` installation method covered in the first tutorial in The Font Installation Guide. In most cases, it will produce a working, though not entirely perfect, result. In other cases, it may fail or it may produce as perfect a result as is possible given the nature of the font.

For the font which is the subject of this question, it should produce a working result.

## Prepare font support package

Start by renaming the `.pfm` `sckr.pfm` and the `.pfb` `sckr.pfb`.

Then

```
pf2afm sckr
mv sckr.afm sckr8a.afm
mv sckr.pfb sckr8a.pfb
```

Then the OP created a file `sck-drv.tex`:

```
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
\recordtransforms{sck-rec.tex}
\latinfamily{sck}{}
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
```

and another `sck-map.tex`:

```
\input finstmsc.sty
\resetstr{PSfontsuffix}{.pfb}
\adddriver{dvips}{sck.map}
\adddriver{pltotf}{sck-pltotf.sh}
\input sck-rec.tex
\donedrivers
\bye
```

Then:

```
tex sck-drv.tex
```

to produce `sck-rec.tex` and a bunch of `.fd`, `.pl` and `.vpl` files. The `.pl` files get converted to `.tfm`:

```
for i in *.pl
do
pltotf $i
done
```

and the `.vpl` to `.vf`:

```
for i in *.vpl
do
vptovf $i
done
```

Then

```
tex sck-map.tex
```

produces `sck.map` and a script `sck-pltotf.sh` which can be run using `sh`:

```
sh sck-pltotf.sh
```

You can now delete the `*.pl` `*.vpl` `sck-rec.tex` `sck-pltotf.sh` etc. as they are no longer needed.

Then you can make a package, `sck.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{DAX}[2015/09/06 v1.0 DAX]

\DeclareOption{default}{%
        \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{sck}}
\ProcessOptions
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sckfamily}{%
        \fontseries{m}%
        \fontshape{n}%
        \fontfamily{sck}%
        \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\sck}{\sckfamily}
\endinput
```

## Testing

At this point, you can say

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{+sck.map}
\usepckage[T1]{fontenc}% optional
\usepackage{sck}

\begin{document}
\sck{Some text}

{\sckfamily More text including off, office, affluent, fluorine, infinitude, --- and --

\slshape This is fake, oblique. 
The results will not be as good as a designed italic or oblique shape.

\upshape\scshape You may also get faked small-caps.
Again, the results won't be as good as real small-caps.

\upshape\itshape Italics should give us the oblique as a substitute.

\par}    
\end{document}
```

and it should work when you `latex` or `pdflatex` the test file, provided your test file is in the same directory as all the font files you've created.

Don't proceed to installation until you are happy with the results.

## Installation

When you are happy with the results of testing, you can install the font files.

For reasons I explain [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i/255711#255711), it is not recommended to install into your personal TEXMF tree unless you have no choice.

Instead, install into your system-wide local TEXMF tree. You can find out where this is using `kpsewhich`:

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL
```

If you are using upstream's TeX Live and haven't changed `texmf.cnf`, then this will likely return a single directory. For example, I get

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

So this is the directory I would use. If you are using a packaged version of TeX Live - from a GNU/Linux distro, for example - then you might get more than one directory. For example, on Arch Linux, you would get

```
/usr/local/share/texmf:/usr/share/texmf
```

Thanks to the OP for this information. In this case, you should pick the directory which is ***not*** managed by your Linux distro's package manager. In most cases, this will begin with `/usr/local`. So, on Arch Linux, you'd use

```
/usr/local/share/texmf
```

In the rest of this answer I refer to the selected directory as `<TEXMFLOCAL>`. If `kpsewhich` returned exactly one result, you can substitute `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)`. Otherwise, substitute the relevant directory path appropriately.

The remaining steps may need to be done with root privileges, depending on your system's configuration.

Very likely, you will need to create some directories here. This is normal.

```
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/type1/public/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/tfm/public/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/afm/public/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/vf/public/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/map/dvips/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/tex/latex/sck
mkdir -p <TEXMFLOCAL>/source/fonts/sck
```

You can use something other than `sck` for the directory name - just substitute appropriately.

Now, from the working directory in which you prepared the font files:

```
mv *.pfb *.pfm <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/type1/public/sck/
mv *.tfm <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/tfm/public/sck/
mv *.afm <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/afm/public/sck/
mv *.vf <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/vf/public/sck/
mv *.map <TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/map/dvips/sck/
mv *.fd *.sty <TEXMFLOCAL>/tex/latex/sck/
mv sck-drv.tex sck-map.tex <name of test file>.tex <notes> <TEXMFLOCAL>/source/fonts/sck/
```

Putting things in `source` is optional and just for reference. I find it useful so I can find things.

Now, you need to update the file name database:

```
mktexlsr <TEXMFLOCAL>
```

There are two ways to enable the `.map` file fragment. One has certain advantages but I'm not sure how it works with Arch's packages, so I suggest the second:

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=sck.map
```

## Retest

You should now be able to drop any root privileges and recompile your test document from another directory, commenting out or deleting the `\pdfmapfile...` line, to get the same results.

Comment: It didnt work for me, because I had files named sck8a.pfm and sck8a.pfb before using `pf2afm`. I allso used comand in different manner than you. I used it like this `pf2asm sck8a.pfb` and not like you did `pf2asm sckr` - mind the file extension and the name which was different in my case. Should renaming before or afterwar `pf2afm` have any influence on the sucess? Maybee I got errors because I provided a file extension and you didn't.

Comment: One more question. Where should I put all these files after compilation? Is this folder fine `~/texmf/fonts/type1/sckr/`?

Comment: @71GA I am not sure what affects the success of `pf2afm`. But whatever you did was fine because I'm using the `.afm` you produced. So there was no problem with the conversion. However, it ***must*** be named `sckr8a.afm` - note the `r`. You could change the `sck` to any other 3 letters. But it needs the form `XYZr8a.afm`. And the `.pfb` ***must*** end up as `sckr8a.pfb` i.e. same name with different extension.

Comment: @71GA The best place to install them is in `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL`. Installing them into you personal TEXMF tree will cause problems which you should be able to avoid by using the local one. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i/255711#255711) for an explanation. (That's about using the `getnonfreefonts` script but it also covers use of `updmap` rather than `updmap-sys`.) I'll extend my answer to cover installation in a bit. But test without installing them first as explained above.

Comment: @71GA Please see edit.

Comment: Can you only fix your anwser - in the second script where you are mooving files `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` returns two folders separated by `:` and the script cant find these folders. =) There should only be one TEX tree there right?

Comment: @71GA Sure. There should definitely only be one directory. I didn't know that could happen. Which directories are they? I've only ever seen one....

Comment: Well when I use command `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` I get this `/usr/local/share/texmf:/usr/share/texmf` and the script therefore fails. It works if I manually replace `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` with either `/usr/local/share/texmf` or `/usr/share/texmf`. With kind regards.

Comment: @71GA Thanks. That's helpful. I've updated the answer to take account of the case where you get multiple directories. This might be common for re-packaged versions of TeX Live from Linux distros - I'm not sure. Did you get this working?

Comment: No this didnt't work. But you can use sed in order to remove everything behind the first `:`. Substitute `<TEXMFLOCAL>`with `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL | sed 's/:.*//'`.

Comment: @71GA The `<TEXMFLOCAL>` is supposed to be substituted with whichever directory is the right one. I don't want to automate selection if there are multiple directories because the first one might not be the correct choice. So I think it is better to explain how you should pick a directory if `kpsewhich` gives you more than one. This means that the scripts cannot be copy-pasted without modification but it is a false convenience to provide scripts which can be if I can't be sure they'll do something reasonable.

Comment: Oh . Well this is true and it is better not to automate this. You are right.

Comment: I got a nice idea. We could use `$1` in place of `<TEXMFLOCAL>`.  $1 expands into the first argument which was passed to the script at the moment of running. =) So we would start the script like this: `sudo ./script /usr/share/texmf`.

Comment: @71GA I think that is a nice idea for your own use, but I would not turn my solution into a script for general use without putting rather more safeguards in place than I do here. Especially since people may run this with root privileges. There are things I'd want to be careful of if publishing a script, and I'm not confident that the things I know to be careful of exhaust the things I should be careful of in that case ;).

Comment: general info about how (La)TeX processes font files: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119488/8666