# Adding a Symbol in own font (Gymsymbols)

Tags: macros, symbols, packages

I'm trying to work out how to add symbols from a special font to my LaTeX-document: I have a true-type-font, in which some by unicode unused chars are displayed as symbols I'd like to use (the font can be gotten [here](http://www.gymsymbol.com/sites/all/themes/gymsymbol/css/components/gymsymbol.ttf)). I would be happy to know, how I can add these symbols.

Basically what the font does is displaying this nonsense:



..as the gymnastics transcription for a tumbling pass:

[image]

(Roundoff-Backhandspring-Salto backward 3/2twist-Roundoff-Double Salto backwards 1/1twist)

I know, for my question this is kind of irrelevant, but I thought you might be intrestet in what I need your help for :)

So I'm looking for a way to do `\roundoff` or something like that and get the  corresponding symbol in the specific font. I hope this is possible and you can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this is a TTF font, there is help [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your difficulty is not installation of the font but rather convenient use of its glyphs, and if you’re using `xetex` or `luatex`, you can create macros like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\gym{gymsymbol.ttf}
\newcommand{\Roundoff}{\gym\symbol{"E002}}
\newcommand{\Backhandspring}{\gym\symbol{"E003}}
\begin{document}
\Roundoff\Backhandspring
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [How can I access a specific glyph in LuaLaTeX/Fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98188) and the linked questions for more details.

Comment: Thanks, it works in XeTeX. I guess there is no easy way to do it simularly without using it?

Comment: Without using `xetex`, you mean?  In `pdftex`?  As far as I know, there are difficult ways to do it in `pdftex`, but no easy ways.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If you read French, there’s a document on installing ornament fonts for `pdftex` at http://jacques-andre.fr/fontex/casseaux.pdf  You may also want to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266025 by @cfr (she has packaged many fonts for `pdftex`).