# Converting Math Symbols from PDF into LaTeX

Tags: pdf

I am trying to extract Math content from LaTeX generated PDF files. Most extracted symbols get extracted fine. However some, such as `\epsilon`, `\Updownarrow`, `\simeq` use non Unicode codes and others such as `\neq` use a combination of non Unicode codes.

- `\epsilon` is written using the embedded font `SCCPFS+CMMI10` and code 017
- `\Updownarrow` using the embedded font `KAXSYH+CMSY10` and code `0x6d (m)`
- `\simeq` using the embedded font `KAXSYH+CMSY10` and code `0x27 (')`
- `\neq` using the embedded font `KAXSYH+CMSY10` and codes `0x36 (/)` and `0x3d (=)`

Before I begin writing a table to map from the glyph code(s) to the equivalent LaTeX I wonder if such a mapping table already exists in the reverse direction for use within LaTeX. After all, somewhere the original `\epsilon`, `\neq` etc. would be getting mapped to one or more glyph codes. The combination cases will require position information also, but that should be there too, in the reverse direction.

EDIT: I tried to lookup this information in the font table but there are no entries in GSUB and GPOS. Is that where I should be looking? Is the information really inside the font?

[image]

EDIT: I tried looking up the mmap file in a text editor but it is mostly hex. Is there a tool for opening it?

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 Resource-CMap
%%DocumentNeededResources: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%IncludeResource: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%BeginResource: CMap (TeXmath-LMR-0)
%%Title: (TeXmath-LMR-0 TeXmath LMR 0)
%%Version: 1.000
%%EndComments
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (TeXmath)
/Ordering (LMR)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /TeXmath-LMR-0 def
/CMapVersion 1.000 def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <FF>
endcodespacerange
96 beginbfchar
<00> <005C00620069006700630069007200630020>
<01> <005C006D0064006C00670062006C006B0063006900720063006C00650020>
<02> <005C0073007100750061007200650020>
<03> <005C0062006C00610063006B0073007100750061007200650020>
<04> <005C0076006100720074007200690061006E0067006C00650020>
<05> <005C0062006C00610063006B0074007200690061006E0067006C00650020>
<06> <005C0074007200690061006E0067006C00650064006F0077006E0020>
<07> <005C0062006C00610063006B0074007200690061006E0067006C00650064006F0077006E0020>
<08> <005C006C006F007A0065006E006700650020>
<09> <005C0062006C00610063006B006C006F007A0065006E006700650020>
<0A> <005C006D0064006C00670062006C006B006400690061006D006F006E00640020>
```

EDIT: I looked up the character for \neq and it was composed of two different fonts so unlikely that this information is in one font. Doing a grep in the texlive directory gives some hints:-

```
% grep -rw neq * | grep -w not
texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex:\def\neq{\not=} \let\ne=\neq
texmf-dist/tex/generic/enctex/utf8raw.tex:\mubyte \neq ^^e2^^89^^a0\endmubyte % U+2260 not equal to
texmf-dist/tex/generic/ofs/ofs-cm.tex:  \def\neq{\not=} 
texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang3.sty:      myfont,n,nat2string,neq,ngon,norm2,normalmap,not,nu_grid,nubspline,%
texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmath/sansmath.sty:% two lines, but it did not work well (unbold +, bold greek, bad \neq)
texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx:\def\neq{\not=} \let\ne=\neq
texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty:  \cs_gset:cpn { not= }    { \neq }
texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex:\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02260}{\ne                       }{\mathrel}{/ne /neq r: not equal}%
texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty:  \cs_gset:cpn { not= }    { \neq }
texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym:\DeclareFlexCompoundSymbol{\neq}{Rel}{\not{=}}
texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathpazo.sym:\DeclareFlexCompoundSymbol{\neq}{Rel}{\not{=}}
texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathptmx.sym:\DeclareFlexCompoundSymbol{\neq}{Rel}{\not{=}}
```

Comment: https://mathpix.com/

Comment: Font packages frequently come with a full font table. I don’t know of a program or database that maps U-encoded fonts to Unicode, but one might exist. Some `inputenc` mappings go the other direction.

Comment: If you have the source or can translate from codepoints to \commands, the `unicode-math` package has a full list of the `\commands` it supports for every Unicode character.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes MathPix is a great alternative but we also need a free option.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor for sharing. For now, I am looking for the equivalent where Unicode is not output into the PDF.

Comment: Right, so if you have a font table for the original font, you might be able to make a map for their unique “encoding,” like you can for OT1 or OML.

Comment: @Davislor Sorry, got that now. Let me check what's there in the font tables. Thanks.

Comment: You could look in the mmap package. It has such mappings for tounicode.

Comment: can you not locate the tex source of the pdf, given that it is using cmmi font it almost certainly was made with tex. The mapping is document specific as you are listing subsetted fonts that just have the glyphs used in that document.

Comment: **For users just wanting a quick two way lookup** a general transcoder such as https://www.johndcook.com/unicode_latex.html will show \updownarrow as Unicode: U+2195 , \simeq as Unicode: U+2243 but will \NOT show the composed \neq which may be Unicode: U+003D & U+0338

Comment: The hex in the cmap-file you are showing  simply maps a glyph number to a command names. E.g. the first (with suitable spaces) is `005C 0062 0069 0067 0063 0069 0072 0063 0020` = `\bigcircle `.  In other cmap-files you can find mappings from glyphs to unicode positions. E.g. `<41> <D835DD38>` where `D835DD38` is the UTF16 version of `U+1D538` (MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL A).

Comment: as Ulrike has pointed out the hex should be easy to process into a tabular form such as 30 30 005C 0062 0069 0067 0063 0069 0072 0063 0020  30 31 005C 006D 0064 006C 0067 0062 006C 006B 0063 0069 0072 0063 006C 0065 0020  30 32 005C 0073 0071 0075 0061 0072 0065 0020  which gives me 00\bigcirc 01\mdlgblkcircle 02\square 03\blacksquare 04\vartriangle 05\blacktriangle 06\triangledown 07\blacktriangledown 08\lozenge 09\blacklozenge 0A\mdlgblkdiamond

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that works for me. Could you please make that an answer.

Comment: What did work for you? I only told you how to read the cmap file.

Comment: Ok, let me go double check what is still missing. Being able to read the cmap file is helpful but I am not sure if I have all the pieces, yet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Himanshu what do you mean? Mathpix is free. Harvard has also made an open source alternative, if by free you mean open source. http://lstm.seas.harvard.edu/latex/

Comment: @MohammedShahid Thanks for suggesting the alternative, will check. Free to use would have been fine but Mathpix api has a fee after 1000 calls - https://mathpix.com/ocr#pricing

Comment: “Is the information really inside the font?” — Yes and no. The “tables” you are looking for are probably the ones in [LaTeX font encoding guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf). More specifically, the standard *math font encodings* for Computer Modern with TeX are OML, OMS and OMX (Appendix A.4, pp. 33–34 in the linked guide). Other math fonts (such as `newtxmath`, `newpxmath` and `mtpro2 lite`) may use entirely different encodings. So I doubt a single “map” is useful.

Comment: For example, for Computer Modern math and plain TeX, `\epsilon` is mapped to `'017 = "0F` in OML; `\Updownarrow` is mapped to `'155 = "6D` in OMS; `\int` is mapped to `'122 = "52` in textstyle and to `'132 = "5A` in displaystyle in OMX. Here `'` indicates octal number and `"` indicates hexadecimal. The LaTeX math font encoding *can* be different and the mapping is (and should be) done by packages.

Comment: Thanks @RuixiZhang. So you are saying that packages do the splitting into glyphs and that the mapping may not always be available in the pdf. This is closest to what I needed. Would you like to make this an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s start with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\testsqrtsign[1]{\sqrtsign{\vphantom{#1}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[
\testsqrtsign{|}\testsqrtsign{\big|}\testsqrtsign{\Big|}\testsqrtsign{\bigg|}\testsqrtsign{\Bigg|}
\]
\end{document}
```

Compile the above code via pdfLaTeX and then open the PDF file via Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. In the opened PDF file, press `Ctrl + F` and type “pqrsvuut” in the Find bar. Press the `Enter` key or the `Next` button, and we find that

> [image: sqrtsign]
>   How bizarre, isn’t?

Inspecting the PDF file further, we find that a font named “cmex10” is embedded. This simple experiment gives you a taste on how mathematical symbols are encoded in default LaTeX (and to certain extent — the original TeX).

---

To address your question

> I wonder if such a mapping table already exists in the reverse direction for use within LaTeX.

The short answer is: Yes.

### Part 1: The default mathematical encodings

According to the [LaTeX font encoding guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf), there are 3 math font encodings by default (Section 2.6 on page 10), namely, `OML`, `OMS` and `OMX`. In particular, Appendix A.4 (pp. 33–34) lists 3 tables showing where exactly each math letter/symbol is encoded.

For instance,

- the “Greek math italic lowercase epsilon” is encoded in `OML` at position `'017` (octal) or `"0F` (hexadecimal), corresponding to the font “cmmi10” (Computer Modern Math Italic 10);
- the “up down double arrow” is encoded in `OMS` at position `'155` (octal) or `"6D` (hexadecimal), corresponding to the font “cmsy10” (Computer Modern Math Symbols 10);
- the “integral sign in `\textstyle`” is encoded in `OMX` at position `'122` (octal) or `"52` (hexadecimal), corresponding to the font “cmex10” (Computer Modern Math Extension 10);

### Part 2: The mapping from commands to slots

The code containing the mapping from commands `\epsilon`, `\Updownarrow` and `\int` to their corresponding slots can be found in [`fontdef.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/base/fontdef.dtx). For instance, we find these declarations:

```
...
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{letters}{"0F}
...
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Updownarrow}
   {\mathrel}{symbols}{"6D}{largesymbols}{"77}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
    \def\int{\intop\nolimits}
...
```

This is the “reverse” table you are asking for:

- `\epsilon` is from `letters`, which is `OML` encoded and is located at `"0F`.
- `\Updownarrow`, *when acts not as a delimiter*, is from `symbols`, which is `OMS` encoded and is located at `"6D`.
- `\intop` is from `largesymbols`, which is `OMX` encoded and *when used in `\textstyle`* is located at `"52`.

### Part 3: Instructing LaTeX to load the actual font files

This part of the code can also be found in [`fontdef.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/base/fontdef.dtx):

```
...
\input  {omlcmm.fd}
\input  {omscmsy.fd}
\input  {omxcmex.fd}
...
```

but seems to be irrelevant to your current question. Feel free to look at [How (La)TeX makes use of font related files […] when selecting fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119467/164314) and related post to learn more. This part is included here because…

### Part 4: Other math fonts and non-standard encodings

The [`newtxmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package provides a complete *upright* Greek alphabet (`\Gammaup`, `\alphaup`, etc.). They are from `lettersA`, which is declared in `newtxmath.sty` as

```
...
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
...
```

where `U` stands for “Unknown”. The corresponding `untxmia.fd` file contains a variety of fonts: “nxlmia”, “zmnmia”, “zcochmia”, “zchmia”, “ntxstx2mia” and “ntxmia”, and their bold versions. In theory, the author can use whatever encodings he/she pleases for these fonts. For `newtxmath`, we see that

```
...
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Gammaup}{\mathalpha}{lettersA}{0}
...
```

So if you write, say `$\bm{\Gammaup}$`, where `\bm` is provided by the [`bm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm) package, then you can get a bold upright Greek uppercase Gamma. In Unicode, “Mathematical Bold Capital Gamma” is encoded at `U+1D6AA`, while in “lettersA” of `newtxmath`, it is encoded at `0` (decimal, the first slot in the font) *in both regular and bold fonts*.

Now you see the problem: There cannot be a single mapping that converts extracted symbols to their corresponding Unicode characters.

Due to the lack of development in math font encodings (see LaTeX font encoding guide, the last 3 paragraphs at the end of Section 1.2), math fonts can have a variety of different “in-house” encodings. Beside `newtxmath`’s “lettersA” (`U`-encoded), there are `amsfonts`’s “AMSa” and “AMSb”, both `U`-encoded; there are `mtpro2`’s (commercial fonts) `LMP1`, `LMP2` and `LMP3` encodings; etc.

### Concluding remarks

There are many math font encodings beside the standard 3 on the market and they are tied to specific fonts. The information about the mapping between input characters and their corresponding font slots can be found in the support LaTeX packages.

Since there are no “universally agreed” math font encodings, one cannot expect the usefulness of a *single* mapping (if it exists) from glyphs back to commands/Unicode characters.

If you simply want to copy-and-paste math formulas in the PDF file, then maybe give [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) a try:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[\int_0^{\pi\pm\epsilon} \sin x \, \symup{d} x = 2 \mp \delta\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: unicode-math]
>   Kneel before the power of `unicode-math`, mortals!

---

Okay — back to default encodings — why can we search “pqrsvuut” for the square root signs? Well, the first 4 extended root signs are encoded in `OMX` at positions `"70`, `"71`, `"72` and `"73`, respectively; while the last “vertical” root sign is pieced together using one `"76`, two `"75`’s and one `"74`. Guess what are usually at positions `"70` through `"76` ;-)

For more information on how LaTeX handles font, the two main references (available at https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-base) are

- Font encoding guide
- Font selection guide

Comment: +1 It was fun reading your detective work.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I’m afraid I’ve spent waaay too much time on font related stuff. A bad habit of procrastination :)

Comment: I appreciate your procrastination :)

Comment: Thanks for the details and the summary in the last paragraph! Are there any books, resources you'd like to recommend to understand font handling in Latex?

Comment: @Himanshu The two main references on LaTeX font handling are *Font encoding guide* and *Font selection guide*, available at https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-base I also added an example illustrating the usage of `unicode-math`, which allows you to, well, work with Unicode. The only drawbacks are that there are way less Unicode math fonts out there in the market (see [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098)), and `unicode-math` itself is actively being developed.