# How do I locate and install a missing font?

Tags: fonts, texlive

I manually installed the CJK package, and I seem to be missing a font. I get the following error message:

`! Font C70/mj/m/n/9/b0=uwmjb0 at 9.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.`

How do I find out which package I need to install, and how do I install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)

Comment: @Werner Not sure pointing out newbies toward the complex science of installing fonts manually isn't just going to get them even more confused... It's the OP's explicit question, but probably not his real intent (getting his document to compile).

Comment: I am OK with installing a font manually, but how do I find *which* font I need to install and which package is it at?

Comment: for future reference, the missing font here is [uhc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/uhc). To discover missing dependencies after a manual install you can issue a `tlmgr install --dry-run cjk` and see what packages are installed alongisde your target package, then procede to install them manually too. If you don't have any tlmgr version installed you may serch for the `uwmjb` string on the internet and you'll eventually find it's uhc

Comment: Thanks! (for the recored, I only needed the manual installation procedure because *tlmgr stopped working*. But it is useful to know that the font name is `uwmjb`, and that the following 0 and the preceding parts can be ignored.)

Comment: @dcmst Make that an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to know the dependencies of a manually installed package **and** you have a working texlive environment, you can run:

`tlmgr install --dry-run <package name>`

to show the package dependencies (not only fonts). In the case of `CJK` the output will be:

```
install: dry run, no changes will be made
[1/8, ??:??/??:??] install: arphic [26878k]
[2/8, 00:00/00:00] install: cjk [1531k]
[3/8, 00:00/00:00] install: cns [2916k]
[4/8, 00:00/00:00] install: fonts-tlwg [5898k]
[5/8, 00:00/00:00] install: garuda-c90 [5k]
[6/8, 00:00/00:00] install: norasi-c90 [10k]
[7/8, 00:00/00:00] install: uhc [3516k]
[8/8, 00:00/00:00] install: wadalab [17450k]
```

then you can download and install the other dependencies manually.

If `tlmgr` is not available you can search the internet for the fontname (`uwmjb`) in your case and you'll eventually find the relevant package.