# Installing the mcq TeX package

Tags: packages

I have Mac OS X 10.7.5 and TeX Live 2012, and "XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998". How do I install the mcq package?

Comment: What *is* the `mcq` package? It is not found on CTAN.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.matapp.unimib.it/~ferrario/var/mcqxelatex.html).

Comment: Yes that's it. How do I run mcq.py on Terminal? If I just type `mcq.py` it says `-bash: mcq.py: command not found`, and if I type `latex mcq.py`, it says  
  
`! You can't use 'macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.1 #
     !/usr/bin/env python`  
  
And my Mac has no such directory as `/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf` which is given by the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`. Could it be hidden? How do I show it?

Comment: Does not any answer in [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) help you? Is a font involved? Then see [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Comment: If it ends with `.py`, it's probably a python file. Maybe `./mcq.py` or `python mcq.py`?

Comment: Acute observation, only I have never used python so I had no idea this was a python file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download the Linux Libertine font, the link is http://www.fontspace.com/linux-libertine. Be sure to download Libertine and not Biolinum. The rest is done by following the instructions on http://www.matapp.unimib.it/~ferrario/var/mcqxelatex.html, bearing in mind that `.py` is the extension for python files which are run by `python FileName.py` on the Terminal. The file is created by that mcq.py program, then you open it in your TeX editor, put the questions and answers in the designated areas and typeset normally. Be sure to use XeTeX or LuaTeX as plain pdfTeX won't work. The strange thing is I never had to move the `.sty` file from my Downloads folder, so that `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` command was pretty useless for me. Besides, the result of that was `/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf`, which I can't access because it does not show up, neither in the Finder, nor in the Terminal where the Library does show up. The only problem now is that `mcq.sty` is found only if the `.tex` file using it is in the Downloads folder.

**Update:**
I stumbled again upon this question while searching for examples to link to from the answer to [this meta SX question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265874/regarding-the-time-required-to-pass-between-acceptance-and-posting-of-an-answer), and there are two ways to fix this "only" problem:

1. Find the directory where LaTeX looks for packages (where the packages from the installed distribution are) and put the mcq folder into it, and then go on terminal and use `sudo texhash`; this isn't tested but it worked when I tried to [install my own package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197012/package-wont-get-loaded).
2. Place the `.sty` in the appropriate "local" directory, as indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197012/package-wont-get-loaded); well, perhaps the indications there are not accurate for your computer; in my case, if `~` is the home directory, they are accurate, but note that my Library was invisible; the Finder has a `Go to Library` command which becomes visible under the `Go` menu when pressing the Option key.

Comment: NO! First: The original source for Linux Libertine is [LinuxLibertine.org](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/). Second: It is already installed or can be so in all big TeX distributions, also in opentype version - the according package is `libertine`.

Answer (score 1):

Just two comments (I wrote `mcq.py`):

If you create, in the directory `/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf/`, a TEXMF tree, there you can install your own packages (or tex files, or image files, or bibtex files... ) - out of the official `texlive/*` distribution.

Example: `/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf/tex/latex/mcq.sty`

`texhash` might be needed after.

About the proper place where to put `mcq.py`, it depends on your `$PATH`. A typical place might be `/usr/local/bin`, after making sure that something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` is in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` . Also, it needs to be executable (check file permissions).

From the "Linux Libertine font" comment I reckon that you could already run it: Linux Libertine is the default font. You can change it to any other font with the proper glyphs (by changing the commands `\squarebox`, `\Ufont`, and setting a different `\setmainfont`), but you should first make sure that there are no missing symbols (check the logfile).

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or use the keystroke <Ctrl> + <K>.