# How to install packages which I am not able to find in TeX Live Utility?

Tags: packages

Using [this tex](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example4.tex) on TeXworks, I get an error. The code is an output from pandoc converting from markdown to tex.

I checked if I have all the packages with TeX Live Utility. I found the followings.

1. When I check `fontenc` I found that I have greek-fontenc package.
2. I am not able find lmodern and fixltx2e
3. For inputenc, I have greek-inputenc
4. I am not able find longtable in TeX Live Utility
5. I have all other packages.

Now my question is how to install packages which I could not find it in TeX Live Utility?

I know  this is a newbie question, but I appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

====

Error

```
fontenc.sty
100
I can't find file `ecrm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000' failed to make ecrm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example of *code* which people can compile (or fail to compile) to reproduce the problem. What you've posted doesn't make it clear what the source of the problem is. I suspect that you have loaded `fontenc` with option `T1` but that the `cm-super` fonts are either not available or not found for some reason. You could load a different font if you have one installed. For example, `\usepackage{lmodern}` might work. But it is kind of hard without seeing the code or knowing really anything about what you have installed or not.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: typing ecrm1000 into the above search box shows lots of solutions to this problem  http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ecrm1000

Comment: note that the packages that you mention `fontenc` `fixltx2e` `inputenc` and `longtable` are all part of the core latex distribution not contributed additions. If you have latex, you have them already.

Comment: General links: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137) and [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423).

Answer (score 1):

I need to run `sudo tlmgr install ec` in the terminal. It works fine now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Note that you seem to have installed a very minimal subset of TeX Live's packages. Unless you are short of disk space or have a very slow connection, I recommended installing a more complete set as it will make your life a lot easier! If you are not short of disk space, in fact, I would recommend just installing the full version. This is especially good if you are relatively new to TeX as it helps to rule out weird errors or strange output due to missing packages. (TL doesn't contain everything but it contains most.)

Comment: How much disk space will be needed for full package installation?

Comment: If you run the installer, it should tell you how much space is required for the scheme or collections you choose. So if full requires too much space, you can customise things and maybe choose medium or tetex instead.

Comment: Could you tell me how to run the installer? Do you mean TeX Live?

Comment: Yes, TeX Live. Details are at https://www.tug.org/texlive/.