# What is happening with my fonts?

Tags: fonts, packages, oldstylenums, logging

I can't quite install the fonts properly and check the log files, nor can I identify if the font is loading properly. That is, I want to choose the typography but can't notice minor differences between several types that may appear.

## Main question: How do I know what fonts are loading?

... and not just the default?

- How do I install and change to other typgraphies?
- How do I identify the fonts compiled in pdf, or log?
- I'm interested specially in [baskervald (and clones) with old number style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319187/is-there-a-way-to-use-baskervald-font-and-old-style-numbers-for-whole-document?noredirect=1#comment784084_319187)
- How do I get a grip to understand the log files

  ---

Relevant?

- [What is the secret to use fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166389/what-is-the-secret-to-use-fonts)
- [How do I use an OpenType font with my LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-do-i-use-an-opentype-font-with-my-latex-document)
- [How do I find out what Chinese fonts are installed with my MacTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223893/how-do-i-find-out-what-chinese-fonts-are-installed-with-my-mactex-installation)

Comment: Your question is a collection of duplicates: [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423), [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919), [Is a “real” Baskerville font available for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100329), [Understanding the Log file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32213)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for input. Should I delete the post? I see no point in keeping up on a unanswered duplicate question.