# How to install correctly simhei.ttf and simsun.ttc for pdflatex on TEX Live 2013

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, truetype

I have simple document (don't think about the meaning of Chinese characters, they are there only for testing purpose):

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper, 11pt]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
第一项
\end{document}
```

If I compile it on my Linux machine, with a fresh complete installation of the TEX Live 2013, using:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --synctex=1 document.tex
```

and both **simhei.ttf** and **simsun.ttc** are in the same folder like **document.tex**, then everything is fine and I get a nice PDF file.

*However*, if any of **simhei.ttf** and **simsun.ttc** are missing in this folder, then I am getting error message. Either

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file simsun.ttc): cannot open TrueType font file for reading
```

or

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file simhei.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for reading
```

After 4 hours of testing and googling I still cannot figure out where to put these two files to avoid necessity to copy these into document root when I need work with Chinese characters again...

So far I have tested (with no luck):

```
~/fonts
/usr/share/fonts/truetype
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/chinese
```

(Additional `fc-cache -fv` performed of course.)

The result of `fc-list :lang=zh-cn` is:

```
NSimSun,新宋体:style=Regular
FangSong,仿宋:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Stand    aard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
KaiTi,楷体:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
SimSun,宋体:style=Regular
Efont Fixed Wide:style=Italic
Efont Biwidth:style=Bold Italic
SimHei,黑体:style=Regular
SimHei,黑体:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Something like `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/public/chinese` should work but you need to run `mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. Never install files by hand into `/usr/local/texlive/YYYY` as that tree should be reserved for the TeX installation itself.

Comment: Are you sure you are using pdflatex when it works? I don't quite see how that could but I'm certainly no expert on CJK fonts.

Comment: Does [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423) help?

Answer (score 2):

Cfr is correct, it was `sudo mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the precise location where you put the two font files?

Comment: (Almost) exactly followed Cfr's advise: fonts saved into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype` and then executed `sudo mktexlsr` (Path in command is not needed.)