# Is pdflatex a symbol link to pdftex in cygwin system

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have three questions on TeXlive 2013 in cygwin.

1. Is pdflatex a symbol link to pdftex? I was surprised to see this in C:/cygwin/bin. As we all know, pdflatex and pdftex are very different commands. I don't know why. Does anyone know how it works?
2. I want to config Texstudio to use tex commands from cygwin. But system file "pdflatex" cannot be executed, and "pdftex.exe" do not recognize the grammar of latex. How can I config pdflatex command in Texstudio?
3. Chinese article compiles clean with Chinese fonts simhei.ttf, simsun.ttc under the directory of the article. I have tried to install fonts, but it seems I have failed. Could anyone help out? I have followed the instructions in [How to install correctly simhei.ttf and simsun.ttc for pdflatex on TEX Live 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168732/how-to-install-correctly-simhei-ttf-and-simsun-ttc-for-pdflatex-on-tex-live-2013)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking several unrelated questions. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: For number 2, where is texstudio installed, inside or outside cygwin? Can you actually use cygwin commands from outside cygwin. And if you need it outside cygwin, shy not just install latex on your base system. That might also fix 3. As for 1,it is likely that it is just a symlink and the system looks at the callers name to determine what happens

Comment: yes cygwin works like unix tex and all the formats using the  same base engine are symlinks, the engine uses the program name (argv[0]) to determine which format to load.  You can make a pdflatex.bat in your windows path  that does `pdftex &latex %1` so windows apps are happier

Comment: texlive 2013 is frozen, texlive 2014 has been out for quite a while, so you may want to update to TL2014 first

Comment: @PaulGessler Sorry, I will separate my questions next time, is that ok?

Comment: @daleif texstudio is installed outside cygwin, and there is no latex on windows. The question 3 is related to Chinese font problem, I have no idea of how to fix it. If 'pdflatex' is a symlink to 'pdftex.exe', how could 'pdflatex' find the grammar of latex? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried 'pdflatex.bat', which has 'pdftex &latex %1'. It doesn't work. I am thinking of installing texlive 2014 on windows directly, as I am not sure whether texlive 2014 in cygwin would be used by texstudio outside cygwin on my windows system. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK cygwin is completely separated from windows. Thus you will need to either install LaTeX (texlive) on Windows or install texstudio inside cygwin.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

TexStudio works with Cygwin TeX Live using the following:

```
Menu -> Options -> Configure -> Commands -> PdfLaTeX:   
"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash" -l  "/cygdrive/c/users/porterb/pdflx.sh"
```

Contents of `pdflx.sh`:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=/cygdrive/c/users/porterb/data/home/tex -output-format=pdf /cygdrive/c/users/porterb/data/home/tex/main.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.