# Problem using Hershey Old English Font font

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use [Hershey Old English Font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/hge/). The code I am using is,

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newfont{\hge}{hge scaled 1500}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hershey Old English Font}
\subsection*{\textbackslash hge}
\normalfont\hge
\input catalogue
\newpage
\normalfont\hge
\input fonttable
\end{document}
```

But I get the following error message,

```
Running hbf2gf.exe...


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)



Couldn't find `h.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font hge.

! Font \hge=hge scaled 1500 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.11 \newfont{\hge}{hge scaled 1500}

?
```

The same code isn't working in Overleaf either. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a METAFONT version of the Hershey font from CTAN here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hershey

This should call more common mechanisms of font generation than`hbf2gf` that seems to be wrongly configured on your system.

ADDENDUM: In case that automatic font generation fails, you can always generate the font by hand, calling

```
mf hge
```

from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

On the page you link to it says "Hershey Old English Font is not part of TEX Live." and ctan only provides the raw metafont-source. That means that you are trying to use a font, that is simply not installed on your system.

You could install it manually (start reading [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) for example), but as long as don't *really* need this specific font, it is definitely easier to find another old style font that suits your needs, e.g. [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html) or use a ttf-font with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.