# Japanese font with good kanji coverage for xelatex on linux

Tags: fonts, xetex, japanese

Can anyone recommend a font that has good coverage of kanji characters that I can use with xelatex on Linux?  My immediate problem is typesetting the name Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).

I'm not sure that a MWE is particularly useful, but I'll be criticised if I don't provide one, so here's one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=FandolSong-Bold.otf,ItalicFont=FandolKai-Regular.otf]{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).
\end{document}
```

The first and third characters of his name are not rendered in this font.

(A constraint that may be relevant is that I am using a 2013 version of xelatex, and cannot easily upgrade.  This rules out certain fonts due to [this bug](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-July/025385.html) in xetex.)

Comment: I don't know Japanese, but you might find one of these free fonts useful? http://www.freejapanesefont.com/ And here is a coverage of how to install fonts in LaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation ... but first, you should see if this web page about Japanese and Chinese fonts is useful: http://latex-my.blogspot.de/2010/06/cjk-support-in-latex.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the ST fonts?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\begin{document}
Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).

\textbf{Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).}

\textit{Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

It seems the ST fonts are for OS X, not linux. Sorry about that.
You may be able to install [Aozora Mincho](http://www.freejapanesefont.com/aozora-mincho-download/), or Google's [Noto Sans CJK](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). Both fonts have multiple weights but of course no italics. You can fake italics if you want to (see below).

Using above example with

`\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=AozoraMincho-bold,AutoFakeSlant=0.15]{Aozora Mincho}`

[image]

and

`\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=NotoSansCJKjp-Bold,AutoFakeSlant=0.15]{Noto Sans CJK JP}`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not, and I can't find them package for Mint Linux.

Comment: What about the [IPAex fonts](http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/#en)? Are you able to install them? No bold or italic though.

Comment: Aozora Mincho aren't packaged for Mint Linux, though I could probably install them by hand. Noto Sans CJK is, unfortunately, one of the fonts that requires a more recent version of xelatex.  However your suggestion of Aozora Mincho got me trying some other fonts with "Mincho" in their name, and Takao Mincho works nicely, and looks to my untrained eye fairly similar to ST Song.  Takao Gothic seems to work as the sans font.  So I have a solution.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the end I went with the Noto fonts and set up a chroot to allow me to run a more recent version of xetex.