# Stix package doesn't work even in simple examples

Tags: errors, packages, stix

I have been trying to get some of the symbols from the `stix` package to work, but for some reason I get errors even in simple toy examples, where there obviously cannot be any clashes with other packages; e.g., this minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$A\subseteq B$
\end{document}
```

On compiling, I get the error

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/LaTeX/zzz.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the '?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\stix.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def")))
No file zzz.aux.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls1stix.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls2stix.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\t1stix.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls1stixscr.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls2stixex.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls1stixfrak.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls1stixbb.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls2stixcal.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls1stixsf.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\stix\ls2stixtt.fd") [1{C:/Use
rs/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\LaTeX\zzz.aux)Trying to make PK font t1-stixgeneral at 720 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The t1-stixgeneral source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font t1-stixgeneral could not be created.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file t1-stixgeneral): Font t1-stixgeneral at 720 n
ot found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Can someone explain what this error means (if my package has a faulty installation, if `stix` doesn't work with my TeX distribution etc.), and what I can do to get around it?

Comment: Sorry for your problems, but it seems that your installation is faulty. Try with the methods you find at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/

Comment: Looks like missing maps files. Call `updmap` on a command line.

Comment: @egreg and UlrikeFisher, I tried all those (including `updmap`), but it still doesn't work; I get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the name(s) of the `.map` file(s) you need to enable. I have the flat Stix-fonts subdirectory included under the main directory `AMA-stix` that came with `WileyNDJ-v2.zip`

Second, there is no `updmap` on MiKTeX. You should instead open a command window with elevated privileges and execute the following command

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=updmap.cfg
```

when the config file opens, add one line corresponding to each `.map` file you have. For example, for me it would be just one line:

```
Map stix.map
```

Have a look here.

[Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)

I created an installer for texlive on linux if anyone is interested. I guess that would go in a separate post.