# How do I install these fonts manually in TeX Live?

Tags: texlive

I want to install `mathrsfs` in my portable TeX Live installation, but `tlmgr` could not find the font/package. I managed to find it (I think) [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/jknappen.zip). The contents of the archive can be browsed [here](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/jknappen/).

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) question's answers about manual font installation are completely unclear to me. Which files do I use and where do I put them? I'm not putting them in `TEXMFHOME` because, as I said, this is a portable installation. Do I have to run some kind of program to register them with the installation?

Comment: How did you install TeXLive? from tug.org/texlive or from the systems repository (Ubuntu et al)?

Answer (score 6):

if you use `tlmgr info mathrsfs` you should get

```
$ tlmgr info mathrsfs
tlmgr: cannot find package mathrsfs, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `mathrsfs' in their title/description:
rsfs - Ralph Smith's Formal Script font

Packages containing files matching `mathrsfs':
jknapltx:
        texmf-dist/doc/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.rme
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
```

so I would assume

```
tlmgr install jknapltx rsfs
```

would install the needed files.

Comment: One can also install `rsfso` which is an (improved?) version by Michael Sharpe.