# Can't get Bera font with Matlab-prettifier

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings, matlab, matlab-prettifier

I've used Matlab-Prettifier in the past to format my Matlab code, but having moved out of ShareLaTeX and into a local environment, I can't seem to get the Bera Mono font. E.g., the code ...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Matlab-Prettifier Setup
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"
\lstset{
style              = Matlab-editor,
basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
mlshowsectionrules = true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
    escapechar=`,
    caption={For educational purposes},
]
if a == b
    a
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

... produces the output without the Bera font:

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGDIS.png)).  Make sure your TeX distribution and all packages are up-to-date.  You might also want to try rebuilding the font cache.

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I checked the log file for font references and found a warning of a one not being found. Installed the Bera font manually and now it all works as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggestions in the comments it turned out the font was simply missing (I'm using a very slim distribution) – a set of warnings could be found in the log file.

Fixed the problem by downloading [font files](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bera/), and installing them by following the instructions in the included Readme file & [these instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88424/150409).