# Matlab Prettifier Package Question

Tags: matlab-prettifier

I am having difficulties changing the font size of the `matlab-prettifier` package. Here is a MWE.
This works great if I am okay with the default font size. But it's too big I think. I'd like to shrink it to something like `footnotesize`.

For reference, I am compiling with LuaLaTex.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Preamble
% ===========================================
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=American]{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
    view([150 25])
    plot(t,sol(:,1))
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Temperature u(0,t)')
    title('Temperature change at center of disc')
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

So I try do something like

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]
    view([150 25])
    plot(t,sol(:,1))
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Temperature u(0,t)')
    title('Temperature change at center of disc')
\end{lstlisting}
```

But it shows up as `TeX Gyre Pagella` (I think) and loses all syntax formatting. Definitely not the MATLAB editor font, like it shows when I use just `style=Matlab-editor`. I also get a warning saying Font shape `TU/fvm/m/n' undefined. Maybe I am missing a font on my system?

Comment: I believe the font family fvm corresponds to the font BeraMono. I tried installing it as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427761/cant-get-bera-font-with-matlab-prettifier?rq=1). Unfortunately I still get the warning TU/fvm/m/n can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of `matlab-prettifier` has the following style definition as the 'base style' (starting at line 447, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf) on page 34):

```
  language               = \languageNormedDefd@mlpr,
  basicstyle             = \color{black}\ttfamily\normalsize,
  breaklines             = true,
  showspaces             = false,
  showstringspaces       = false,
  upquote                = true,
  rulecolor              = \color{black!67},
  numberstyle            = \color{black!33},
  mlscaleinline          = true,
  mlonlyheader           = false,
```

Adjusting the second line here results in smaller output:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Preamble
% ===========================================
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=American]{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily\footnotesize]
    view([150 25])
    plot(t,sol(:,1))
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Temperature u(0,t)')
    title('Temperature change at center of disc')
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]