# MikTeX/DVIPS fails to install a font

Tags: fonts, dvips, miktex2.9

I'm trying to compile a file using dvips. I use MikTex 2.9 on Windows 10.
However, MikTeX fails to install the font I use: @antquabr7t. (See error output below.) Alternatively, I try to include a similar font with \usepackage but this also fails with similar errors: 
E.g. with 
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

**Questions**:

1- How can I solve this problem?

2- How can I compile with dvips including this font?

3- Also, is this font so exotic that other people wouldn't be able to print the file, once the ps file is converted to pdf via ps2pdf?

Here is the output I get from MikTeX:

> 2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose @antquabr7t 16592 8000 2+592/8000 ljfour
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font @antquabr7t at 16592 DPI...
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Specified BDPI (8000) doesn't match ljfour resolution (600).
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Specified BDPI (8000) doesn't match ljfour resolution (600).
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
>   2018-11-04 22:08:34,292Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
>   2018-11-04 22:08:35,609Z INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose

Minimal Working Example, issuing similar mistakes with the \usepackage option:

```
%&latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   

\begin{document}

\title{Article Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Testing fonts
\end{abstract}

\section{About Template}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

For the Min Work Exmple above I get the following error:

> 2018-11-05 13:06:40,434Z INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --verbose md-chr8y
>   2018-11-05 13:06:40,443Z FATAL miktex-makemf - The md-chr8y source file could not be found.
>   2018-11-05 13:06:40,443Z FATAL miktex-makemf - The md-chr8y source file could not be found.
>   2018-11-05 13:06:40,443Z FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
>   2018-11-05 13:06:40,443Z FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
>   2018-11-05 13:06:40,443Z FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0

### EDIT: Solutions thus far:

1- Use MikTex Console to install the fonts needed: go to packages in MikTex Console and find the font to install. Then update database (by right click in that window).

2- As user KGO suggeted: must execute updmap.exe in dir "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64"

**Remaining problem**: Question 3 above.

Comment: seems to be an infrequent problem with a font map file various suggestions include at correct level (user and admin if system wide),  **use** package manager if possible to include the ctan package *only* if that's not possible then resort to manual unpack and ensure correct files are in position in your txmf tree & fndb is updated via either *console tasks* or initexmf --mkmaps (if not in your start up) & initexmf --update-fndb Also you could in your preamble try \usepackage{=...} \pdfmapfile{+....map} For a good guide see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation

Comment: @Jack what is the procedure you followed for font installation?

Comment: I use simply \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{@antquab}

Comment: Also it would be good to get a bit of up votes, so that I can have more privilege here :D

Comment: @KJO, thanks. I read the manual before asking; I find it extremely complicated...I thought maybe there are more elegant and efficient solutions.

Comment: @KJO, " *use package manager if possible to include the ctan package*"---Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this... Or what does it mean...which package manager? what is a ctan package?

Comment: having problems clarifying where your fonts come from Antqua is uncommon Antiqua (is often applied as a typy1 office 2010 font) but available as a ctan package here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw and supported by package https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/urwvf/ in your second set of errors that has switched to md-chr8y which has a potential solution here https://blog.roland-kluge.de/?p=895 In any case it is ensuring font mappings are updated that seem to be core of problems In MiKTeX console you have a TASK refresh font map files (often --mkmaps is included in MiKTeX start cmd file)

Comment: I cant reproduce error on my updated systems however this is likely triggered by mathdesign package calling on a selection of fonts that are not correctly mapped in MiKTeX there is a utility in your \MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\ directory called updmap.exe you could try running that

Comment: Thanks KJO! Some progress indeed: I use now a similar font crimson, and updating the db it worked fine. Only now I need to use the explicit options: dvips myfile.dvi -z -P pdf, and now dvips errors with: "Trying to make PK font ecss1200 at 8000 DPI...Sorry... miktex-makepl did not succeed" and the same for "Trying to make PK font ecss1000 at 8000 DPI..." and "Trying to make PK font ecsi1200 at 8000 DPI..."

Comment: I've now sorted out the above problem also: took off "\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}" from the Tex file. Hooray!
The only problem left: do you think that the end users would be able to print such a pdf file? Maybe they don't have the font? How shall I include the font in the PDF?

Comment: sorry was busy elsewhere so don't have time to look too close but depending on the way a pdf is constructed the format was designed to allow "embedded fonts or subsets as required" or enough information for another system to closely approximate the font, surest test is to ask someone with a different system (mac & unix) to reply with a screenshot of your windows pdf in their viewer, problematic single characters tend to be fractions like 3/4 7/8, square root symbols etc. unusual accents not the basic ones

Comment: Since your conversion should use Ghost Script PS2PDF there are arguments you can add to remove fonts etc. However ordinarily the pdfwrite device goes to considerable lengths to preserve fonts from the input as fonts in the output. Ensure GS is not from v8.1 (buggy) to 8.54 (fixed) For param's you can introduce see https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm. it may need  experimentation to find how to add cmds in an editor but if using the command line you can either build a .cmd file or use the @params.in command Most important is having correct GhostScript or bin folder on your path.