# How can I use Fira Code with ligatures in pdflatex?

Tags: listings, verbatim, typewriter

Basically, I've come to really like [Fira Code and its ligatures](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) while coding, and I'd like to use it for my code listings in LaTeX, too. Specifically, I am looking for a way to use Fira Code with ligatures enabled as a monospaced typeface, in the `\texttt`, `listings` or `verbatim` environments, in `pdflatex`.

I understand it can be used with little extra work in `xelatex`, according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/LaTeX-instructions), but how about `pdflatex`?

Comment: For `pdflatex` it's a *lot* of extra work. Basically you have to install the font manually, as pdflatex cannot access system fonts. For details, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423/24974

Comment: pdftex can only have 256 characters in each font so to make an opentype font available you need to split it up into multiple fonts and arrange macro layer support so that pdftex knows which font each character is in