# droid font style changes the default LaTeX font style

Tags: fonts

I'm having problems with the droid font style, since according to [its documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/fonts/droid/doc/fonts/droid/droid.pdf) by just loading it on the document it changes the default font. It also changes the font that `minted` uses for typesetting the code, and I just want to use it on the titlepage and then, use the default LaTeX font for the whole document. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % I'm using XeLaTeX
\usepackage{droid}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        My title with droid font
    \end{titlepage}
    \fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
    \section{A section}
    This text is in lmr style, but not the section title.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here.  One is that you’re trying to mix legacy NFSS font families and modern fonts with `fontspec`.  (This is possible, but more complicated than you need.)  The second is that you want to format your chapter/section titles, but you haven’t loaded a package to do that (such as KOMA-Script’s `scrlayer` or `titlesec`).  A third, trivial one is that you’re using even and odd pages without the `twoside` option to your document class.

Here’s a really ugly hack that makes only the minimal changes to your document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % I'm using XeLaTeX
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\newfontfamily\DroidSerif{Droid Serif}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering\DroidSerif
        My title with droid font
    \end{titlepage}
    \section{\DroidSerif A section}
    This text is in lmr style, but not the section title.
\end{document}
```

This is so basic, the section number is in a different font than the section title.

Here is a more full-featured solution using KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass[headsepline, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} % I'm using XeLaTeX
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\newfontfamily\DroidSerif{Droid Serif}

\title{My Title with Droid Serif}
\author{Martin}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lefoot{\pagemark}
\rofoot{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\DroidSerif\bfseries\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{title}{\DroidSerif}
\addtokomafont{section}{\DroidSerif}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\DroidSerif}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
       \maketitle
    \end{titlepage}

    \section{A section}
    This text is in lmr style, but not the section title.

    \newpage
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

If you’re required to use PDFLaTeX, you need to remove `\usepackage{fontspec}` and add the appropriate NFSS commands.  Load `droid`, and then `lmodern` to override it.  The font family of Droid Serif is `fdr`.  Although I don’t recommend this if you can use XeLaTeX, here’s a MWE:

```
\documentclass[headsepline, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{droid}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand\DroidSerif{\fontfamily{fdr}\selectfont}

\title{My Title with Droid Serif}
\author{Martin}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lefoot{\pagemark}
\rofoot{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\DroidSerif\bfseries\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{title}{\DroidSerif}
\addtokomafont{section}{\DroidSerif}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\DroidSerif}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
       \maketitle
    \end{titlepage}

    \section{A section}
    This text is in lmr style, but not the section title.

    \newpage
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\newfontfamily\myfont{<name of font>}` did not solved the problem at all, as [this tutoral](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251) suggests (I'm using XeLaTeX). I've followed the steps to install the font manually using the instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) (supposingly) without errors. Could you post a compilable code?

Comment: @Martin How’s this?

Comment: Thank you! As I progress with LaTeX over the years it becomes more and more complicated, specially font-related topics.