# Is it possible to install a specific .sty using apt?

Tags: packages

For some purpose I need to have `fontawesome.sty'. This .sty is a part of texlive-fonts-extra package which can be installed using apt. But I don't want to install whole texlive-fonts-extra package.

Is there a way to install 'fontawesome.sty' only and not whole of texlive-fonts-extra.

Comment: In theory yes: You could get the package from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) and install it manually (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864). However, you risk running into compatibility issues when you manually install a package from CTAN, especially if you install it with a TeX live from the Linux repositories (which is often quite outdated), since you can only get the newest version from CTAN. In my experience font packages are also much harder to install than 'just a `.sty`'. **So in practice I strongly recommend you install the package via `apt`.**

Comment: For fonts see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423/35864