# What alternatives are there to allrunes for displaying futhark?

Tags: packages, alphabet

The February 2020 release of LaTeX introduced a `\swdefault` command for working with "swash" text which, unfortunately, breaks the [allrunes](https://ctan.org/pkg/allrunes) package, which has a `\swdefault` command of its own.  Now any attempt to typeset a LaTeX document that uses allrunes fails with "`! LaTeX Error: Command \swdefault already defined.`"

Until allrunes is updated to no longer have this command, how can one typeset text in runes/futhark?  If the answer involves extracting individual glyphs from the package, the ones I'm interested in are `\textarc{d}` (ᛞ, U+16DE) and `\textarc{w}` (ᚹ, U+16B9).

Comment: You can install a separate rune-font package that uses the Unicode standard and then call the glyphs directly with \char. The creator of the allrunes package (http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklu/personal/carl/allrunes/) recommends these fonts: https://folk.uib.no/hnooh/runefont/Gullskoen.html (and Gullhornet below). And here are instructions on how to install a font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allrunes will need a real overhaul to make it compatible with the improved series handling in LaTeX. But if you need only the two symbols you mentioned you can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\DeclareFontShapeWithSizes}[5]{%
  \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{%
   <5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83> #5}{}}

\newcommand{\DeclareRuneSeparators}[1]{} %if needed copy the whole definition

\input{arc.fd}

\begin{document}
abc \textarc{d} \textarc{w}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sty file from here: [arXiv-safe](https://github.com/viking-sudo-rm/allrunes). It replaces allrunes.dtx

`\swdefault` has been renamed to `\swdefaultpatch`

The simplest is to save it to your working directory.