# Archivo (font) not found? TeX Live 2019

Tags: fonts

I use TeX Live 2019 from Debian Buster. I installed `texlive-fonts-recommended` and `texlive-fonts-extra`, and updated font cache. I want to use [Archivo](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/archivo/). If I try

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I get with pdflatex:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Archivo.sty' not found.
```

How can I make this work? Preferably with the TeX installation I already have? Can I just download the zip from the font catalogue and install that in my user directory somehow?

---

Here is how far I got with manual installation

```
$ kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/share/texmf

$ cd /usr/local/share/texmf
$ mkdir fonts
$ mkdir tex
$ sudo unzip ~/Downloads/archivo.zip -d .
Archive:  ~/Downloads/archivo.zip
   creating: ./archivo/
   creating: ./archivo/vf/
  inflating: ./archivo/vf/Archiv0-Bold-lf-t1.vf  
  inflating: ./archivo/vf/Archiv0-Bold-tlf-ly1.vf  
...
$ sudo mv archivo/latex tex/
$ sudo mv archivo/* fonts/
$ sudo mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
$ sudo fc-cache
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=archivo.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     Archivo.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     archivo.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.

$ sudo mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=archivo.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

But still cannot render latex:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.9)  26 MAY 2021 19:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/Archivo.sty
Package: Archivo 2020/12/30 (Carl-Clemens Ebinger autoinst) Style file for Arch
ivZero fonts.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/10/05 v1.2f UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A5 (
...
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
...
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty
Package: mweights 2017/03/30 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight 
font packages. 
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 66.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 94.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 8.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ArchivZero-OsF on input
 line 8.

(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/T1ArchivZero-OsF.fd
File: T1ArchivZero-OsF.fd 2020/12/30 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/ArchivZ
ero-OsF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ArchivZero-OsF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.95pt on input line 8.
\c@mv@tabular=\count89
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count90
 [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1503 strings out of 494394
 21750 string characters out of 6172449
 68686 words of memory out of 5000000
 5224 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6474 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,33p,215b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file Archiv0-Regular-osf-t1--base): Font Arch
iv0-Regular-osf-t1--base at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Now what...?

Comment: You might try downloading the package from CTAN and installing in the `texmf-local` tree. It is in TeX Live from the 2020 release.

Comment: @egreg thanks, `texmf-local` tree..., any pointers how to do that?

Comment: I'm reading https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation

Comment: @egreg I tried, but somehow I am doing something wrong with the map file. I also tried `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=ArchivZero.map` which is the name in the directory. I still always end up with `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for Archiv0-Regular-osf-t1--base.`

Comment: @egreg ok, found the problem, my first run of `updmap-sys --enable` put wrong name in `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` and then always choked.

Answer (score 1):

So manual installation from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation), these were my steps:

```
$ kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/share/texmf

$ cd /usr/local/share/texmf
$ sudo mkdir fonts
$ sudo mkdir tex
$ sudo unzip ~/Downloads/archivo.zip -d .
Archive:  ~/Downloads/archivo.zip
   creating: ./archivo/
   creating: ./archivo/vf/
  inflating: ./archivo/vf/Archiv0-Bold-lf-t1.vf  
  inflating: ./archivo/vf/Archiv0-Bold-tlf-ly1.vf  
...
$ sudo mv archivo/latex tex/
$ sudo mv archivo/* fonts/
$ sudo mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
$ sudo fc-cache
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=ArchivZero.map
...
$ sudo mktexlsr
...
```

When you put the wrong name in `Map=`, you end up with bad contents in `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`, so you have to edit that file and remove the invalid map names.