# Change or add updmap paths for installing fonts

Tags: fonts, linux, update, installing-fonts, font-map

After an exhausting search, I've seen that default path for installing new fonts manually is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` (`TEXMFLOCAL`).

But when I put my files under the tree structure of that path and it comes the time to run `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map` or `sudo updmap-sys` (based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)) it say me that isn't searching in that directory, instead only in the following three:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Shortly, I can't install fonts in that path due this `updmap` configuration.

Is there any way to add the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` path to `updmap` search?

Comment: Which TeX Live installation are you running?

Comment: You seem to be using backslashes, not forward slashes? is that just a typo in your post, or what you’re typing on the command line? That would definitely break your commands.

Comment: When you type `whereis updmap-sys`, does it find the correct installation? On some systems (such as a custom TeX Live installation on Debian) you need to run `sudo -E $(kpsewhich updmap-sys) -enable Map=mtpro2.map`. This calls the correct version with and preserves your environment.

Comment: Although, on those, I declare an alias in my profile to avoid having to type that.

Comment: @Davislor 1. 2021. 2. Sorry, LaTeX commands habbit, already corrected. 3. Output for `whereis updmap-sys`: `updmap-sys: /usr/bin/updmap-sys /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap-sys /usr/share/man/man1/updmap-sys.1.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it appears that you have two different TeX live installations on your system, the system one in `/usr/bin/updmap-sys`, which probably was installed by your package manager, and a custom installation in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/`, which was probably installed manually.

The one in your system path is being searched first, but is out-of-date and only half-functional.  You want to make sure that  `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` appears in your `PATH` before `/usr/bin`.  One way to do that [is here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/553305#553305)

You might additionally want to run

```
sudo -E $(kpsewhich texhash)
sudo -E $(kpsewhich updmap-sys) -enable Map=mtpro2.map
```

The `sudo -E $(kpsewhich ...)` might be necessary for the command to run with the correct search path and environment.  Running `texhash` might be necessary for the `updmap-sys` command to find the map file in the file index.  I usually also set

```
alias update-tex='sudo -E $(which tlmgr) update --self --all'
```

so that I can update my installation with the command `update-tex`.

You’ll also find the commands I use to install and update my TeX distro as the system user `tex`, not as `root`, which means that any install script I run at least doesn’t rootkit my machine.  This involves passing the `sudo` command the additional flag `-u tex`, usually through an `alias`.

Pragmatically, though, an installation script running as the `tex` user can modify an executable that I frequently run as my user account, which can then read and alter all my user files.  You might reasonably conclude that getting root is not what should concern us.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` is the first in my `PATH`. The `sudo -E` commands appears not to work, it prints: `usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V`... for both.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez Which OS and distro? Check the `man` page for the correct option to preserve the environment.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, when I run `sudo --help` effectively it tells me its `-E`, but I don't know why I can't run your command.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez Is the `$(kpsewhich texhash)` part not working? Is that giving you a pathname?

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez So, that’s the problem.  If `kpsewhich` is installed, the shell doesn’t seem to be finding it in the `PATH`. Which means that, probably, the other commands don’t work either. Make sure your path is set correctly. You might want to `find /usr -name "kpsewhich" -print` to be sure where it is.

Comment: It's in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich` and `/usr/bin/kpsewhich`, Do I add that path to my PATH?

Comment: @AlbertoLópez `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` should be in your path, before `/usr/bin`. The link in my answer explains how to put it there. Once you save the commands to a file named something like `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh`, open a new login shell with `exec bash -login`, or reboot, and it should work.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` is the first entry in my `PATH`, and when I run `find /usr -name "kpsewhich" -print` it shows the two paths in my latest comment. Should I add that two paths to my PATH?

Comment: Something is goofed up on your installation. Maybe the file permissions, but I’m not sure. Maybe you’re using a shell other than bash.

Comment: I'm using normal terminal in ubuntu, it's the same doesn't it?