Installing Literaturnaya Font on Miktex
I am trying to install the Literaturnaya font
(https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cyrillic/literat/) to be used with miktex.
I have seen a response for how to do it on TeXlive etc, but canoot figure out how to do so properly on miktex.

You can see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation
